# How to flag a suspected cracked account?

Tags: discussion, flags, spam

Since the owner of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532721/facebook-development-in-localhost/17873081#17873081) has been unobtrusive for the past three years, I would not suspect him for spamming. Nevertheless, six identical spammy answers have been posted within minutes. Should this be flagged as spam though, since this might lead to bad consequences for the user?

Comment: Sure, flag as spam. IMHO priority 1 is to get rid of spam post. Let's deal with any possible fallout after that.

Comment: You can always go for a custom flag, explaining the situation.

Comment: @Bart I did, but I am missing an `urgent` option on the `custom flag`

Comment: "Crisis alert! Spam attack!"

Comment: You just did. Flag the spam, meta the concern.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just flag one of the posts as 'other' and explain what's going on. There's also a *very* good chance that the system has raised some additional flags to alert the moderators of duplicate content, quality, etc. Your flag on top of these adds even more validation and context, and the mods can jump in quickly.

Spam generally enjoys an *extremely* short life on Stack Overflow, the posts will likely be spam flagged into deletion possibly before the moderators even see the flags. If that's the case, then they have context from you *right there* in their dashboard to explain the 'carnage'.

You can post here if you really think more eyes are needed immediately, but be aware that this will cause quite a few people to take a sudden and potentially destructive interest in a specific user - so do so with care. In most cases, a descriptive flag is all you really need to do.

Comment: Would the conclusion `It might be always better to use custom instead of spam` and `There is no need for an urgent option on custom` be valid?

Comment: @bummi You can still flag the posts as spam, that allows the community to take care of it without requiring moderator intervention. But if you see a strong pattern from a particular user, it's still a good idea to raise a custom mod flag *also*. And why would there need to be an "urgent" option? Everyone thinks their flags are "urgent".

Comment: "the posts will likely be spam flagged into deletion possibly before the moderators even see the flags" - Yet another reason why we should probably have some kind of system-raised warning when posts are destroyed by the community. This almost always warrants us looking into the account behind them.

Comment: @BradLarson I believe the flags are still left in the queue even if the post is deleted after crossing the threshold (6). I have to double check that, though, because every time I've seen it they've also had a few 'other' flags tacked on.

Comment: @TimPost - I don't believe this piece of trash was ever seen by a moderator: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16910553/19679 (an advance warning about language to anyone following that link) and the account deleted only after someone put a custom flag on another post by them.

Comment: @BradLarson It is in fact by design that they don't. I'm not sure _why_ I remember them 'sticking', it must have just been due to other flags being tacked on that weren't auto cleared when the threshold was hit. The idea is, this is something the community handled, you shouldn't have to look at it. It does make a _little_ sense to raise a flag if a user has had multiple posts spam flag deleted, but how rare would it be to see that happen without a diamond taking notice?

Answer (score 2):

I would custom flag one of his posts explaining exactly what's wrong. A moderator has the tools to handle it.

Alternatively, a post here on meta works too.