# Raise an automatic flag for spammers

Tags: feature-request, spam, automatic-flags

When a post gets six spam flags, it is [deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/how-does-the-spam-flag-work).  However, the user account remains in the system.

When this happens, an automatic flag should be raised to allow moderators to check the account to see if it needs to be destroyed, similar to the PostVandalismDeletionsAuto flag.

I will periodically run searches, such as https://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aquestion%20deleted%3a1, and see blatant spam that has been deleted, but the spammer's account remains.

When combined with the feature that will [allow moderators to annotate account deletion/deconstructions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/192847), SE will be able to get better information on the spammers.

Comment: I'd rather just [automatically delete users that had all of their posts removed as spam](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165311/auto-delete-destroy-1-rep-user-when-their-post-is-deleted-as-spam). Less work for us mods.

Comment: @MadScientist Given the choice between this feature, or that one, automagic deletion would be best.  But, I think at least one of these should be done.

Comment: Some people use spam flags for mentioning your own blog, or a book you wrote, or a course you offer. I would be very wary of auto deleting accounts.

Comment: @KateGregory My proposal is restricted to 1 rep accounts, it would not automatically delete accounts that have some upvoted content associated.

Comment: I fully support this. [I've been wanting some kind of system flag for community-deleted spam for a while](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190485/how-to-flag-a-suspected-cracked-account/190493#comment590908_190493), because some spammers and trolls have abused the site for longer than they should simply because the community got to them before any moderator saw their trash. The only thing I'd add to the above is that I wouldn't restrict it to spam flags, but also do this for offensive ones.

Comment: Related occurrence at [english.SE]: [Spammer's not been "canned"](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4756/spammers-not-been-canned?cb=1).

Comment: Auto-deletion won't catch every case, so I'd like to see a flag regardless.  I've seen users with a mix of spam and non-spam posts (one non-spam "anchor" before spamming, for instance); auto-deletion can't *and shouldn't* apply in such cases, but moderators still need to be made aware.

Comment: Related - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237235/is-there-a-way-for-a-moderator-to-search-for-posts-that-were-deleted-as-spam

Answer (score 11):

I see nothing wrong with raising a flag for mods if an account has suspicious activity, such as blatant SPAM combined with low/no rep.  However, please don't allow it to become SkyNet and auto-ban; I'd feel better if there was some manual intervention.

Another [good request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29006/function-to-flag-users-as-spambots?rq=1) was proposed a few years back, though I can't tell from the post if the feature was, indeed, created.

EDIT: Additionally, see [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165311/auto-delete-destroy-1-rep-user-when-their-post-is-deleted-as-spam?rq=1) which is in the same vein (though I'm not sure it's a duplicate).

Comment: The linked question isn't a dup.  This is just a new flag type, to let mods know about possible spammers.  The linked question is automagic destruction for 1 rep spammers.

Answer (score -3):

It would work well on regular users that went on spamming spree, but will it really help anything against serious spammers? I have no statistics to support it, but from what I know, creating a new account is easy enough, so that the spammers won't care about creating new account for each spam message.

In order to catch such things, you should detect the following:

- more than  spam posts with link to  within  days
- more that  spam posts from  withing  days
- more than  spam posts from  withing  days
- more than  spam posts with  in url shortener within  days

The moderator should be able to report the problem to the developer, which could to the following:

- ban links do domain
- ban keyword in link
- ban IP address/group
- ban posts with  in link
- ban posts with  in title

The bans should be possible to put either globally or on single site.

This would target the single-account spammers as well, because a spammer posting unique spam links is a rather unique case (once again, I don't have official statistisc, but from what I know, a single spammer is normally spamming the links to the same target site/product).

Comment: We already have anti spam mechanisms in place. But it isn't bulletproof and some spam still gets through. I really like the idea of an automatic flag being raised as soon as a post gets deleted with 6 spam flags.

Comment: To add to what Second Rikudo said, this is partially to prevent some new spam, but also to cleanup after they are done.  I routinely find users, sometimes with accounts across multiple sites, who have had spam automatically deleted but their account is still in the system.