# Is there a way (for a moderator) to search for posts that were deleted as Spam?

Tags: support, search, moderator-tools, spam, deleted-posts

When site users are on the ball they should be spam flagging posts so they get removed from the front-page and eventually deleted. All this happens without moderator involvement.

However, sometimes the spammer stays quiet for a while then rears his/her ugly head again and re-spams (until the spam-ram takes care of them anyway).

So, sometimes in those quiet moments I like to go and look for such posts to give the spam-ram a bit of a helping hand and get rid of those users before they cause trouble again.

Currently I just do a search for `deleted:1` and then sorting by newest. But obviously this returns everything that has been deleted.

Another mod suggested searching for `deleted:1 score:-20..-2` which gives slightly better results, but still shows 'real' posters too.

Is there a way to search just for deleted spam posts?

Comment: It's not obvious you are talking about a moderator-only request, I've clarified this.

Comment: Anyway, back to topic, I guess they can add search operator like "spam:1" to make the search trivial. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard yeah, that'd work for me.

Comment: A "spam:1" query option would be particularly useful on Stack Overflow, where we tend to get a lot of spam in the late night U.S. hours when few moderators are around. Would be nice to come in and destroy all of the spam accounts that community members tagged before we saw them.

Comment: @Bard that's true, another option is to raise a system flag when a post is deleted by 6 spam/offensive flags. (Pretty sure it was already suggested)

Comment: [This MSE feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/192882/214632) is at least somewhat related. Either would be nice to help mods find users who have spam/offensive posts which were deleted by the community.

Comment: @ArthurFischer: Indeed it is. Slightly different but a similar approach. I'd take that one or this one, whichever is easier to implement really.

Comment: The search kludge can be improved by also including `locked:1 migrated:0`. (On math.SE this reduced the number of matches by more than 95%. Still some false positives, but much better.)

Answer (score 6):

This won't get *only* spam, but it'll get spam and offensive posts and you might want to know about the latter too.  This is what I use:

> deleted:1 locked:1 [created:3d..]

Posts deleted by spam and offensive flags are locked as well.  Adding a date filter that covers from when you last checked makes review easier.

The problem with score-based searching is that your results will be polluted with Roomba cleanup, VLQ deletions, and the like, and can miss some spam/offensive deletions if another moderator flag-deleted it or somebody upvoted it.  And yes, I've seen upvoted spam.

This query will also catch migration stubs and merge stubs, and anything that was manually locked before being deleted.  It's not *only* spam/offensive, but on my sites the rest of that stuff is small enough in comparison to the spam that it's not disruptive.

Comment: This also catches deleted migration stubs and merge stubs.

Comment: @gparyani oh, true.  We have so few of those, compared to spam, on my sites that it hadn't registered.  I'll edit.

Comment: Unfortunately, on Stack Overflow, the first 1026 pages out of 1926, sorted on votes, are all positively scored implying that they aren't spam but the migration stubs/manual locks/merged posts.  :-( (But yep, I add a negatively scored filter usually while searching for spam, so they won't be detected)

Comment: This also doesn't catch posts that were flagged as Spam/R/A and deleted via delete votes but are still hidden behind the revision link.

Comment: @Mithrandir true, but possibly less-clearly spam.  Sure, some 20k-rep users delete when they should spam-flag instead, but sometimes spam flags are wrong even if the post is a link-only answer that should be deleted.

Answer (score 4):

For spam posts reported by [SmokeDetector](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291301/295232), there is a database of posts on metasmoke, which offers the option to [show recent posts by site](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/posts/by-site) or [more extensive search options](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/search).

If you're not looking for spam posted during the last week, there's a [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/646101/806591/deleted-spam-offensive-posts) to search for deleted posts with spam or rude/abusive flags (which doesn't mean they were *deleted* as spam or rude/abusive).