# Can a machine be taught to flag spam automatically?

Tags: discussion, flags, spam, robots

TL;DR: [We](https://charcoal-se.org/people.html) did it, so... yes.

---

### What is this?

Charcoal is [the organization](https://charcoal-se.org/people.html) behind the [SmokeDetector](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/SmokeDetector) bot and other [nice things](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE). This bot scans new posts across the entire network for spam posts and reports them to [various chatrooms](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/SmokeDetector/wiki/Chat-Rooms) where people can act on them. If a post has been created or edited, anywhere on the network, we've probably seen it. The bot utilizes our knowledge of how spammers work and what they have previously posted to come up with common patterns and rules to detect spam in the new and updated posts. You've likely seen the SmokeDetector bot if you visit chatrooms such as [Tavern on the Meta](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta), [Charcoal HQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq), [SO Close Vote Reviewers](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) and others across the network. Over time, the bot has become very accurate.

Now we are leveraging the years of data and accuracy to automatically cast spam flags. With approximately 58,000 posts to draw from and over 46,000 true positives, we have a vast trove of data to utilize.

### What problem does this address?

To put it simply, **spam**. Stack Exchange is one of the most popular networks of websites on the Internet, and *all* of it gets spammed at some point. Our statistics show that we see about 100 spam posts per day that get past the system filters.

A decent chunk of this isn't the type you'd want to see at work (or at all). The faster we can get this off the home page, the better for all involved. Unfortunately, it's not unheard of for spam to last several hours, even on the larger sites such as Graphic Design.

Over the past three years, efforts with Smokey have significantly cut the time it takes for spam to be deleted. This project is an extension of that, and it's now well within reach to delete spam within seconds of it being posted.

### What are we doing?

For over 3 years, SmokeDetector has reported potential spam across the Stack Exchange network so that users can flag the posts as appropriate. Users have provided feedback to inform the bot on whether the detection was correct or not (referred to as "feedback"). This feedback is stored in our web dashboard, [metasmoke](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com) ([code](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/metasmoke)). Over time, we've used this feedback to evaluate our patterns ("reasons") and improve our accuracy. [Several](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/reason/106) of our [reasons](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/reason/21) are over 99.9% [accurate](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/reason/61).

Early last year, and after getting a baseline accuracy from [jmac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1933347/jmac) (thank you!), we realized we could use the system to automatically cast spam flags. On Stack Overflow the current accuracy of users flagging spam posts is 85.7%. Across the rest of the network users are 95.4% accurate. We determined we can beat those numbers and eliminate spam from Stack Overflow and the rest of the network even faster.

Without going into too much detail (if you really want it, it's available on our [website](https://charcoal-se.org/flagging)), we leverage the accuracy of each existing reason to come up with a weight indicating how certain the system is that a post is spam. If this value exceeds a specific threshold, the system will cast up to three spam flags on the post. We cast multiple flags utilizing a number of different users' accounts and the Stack Exchange API. Via metasmoke, users are given the opportunity to [enable their accounts to be used to flag spam](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/flagging/ocs) (you can too, if you've made it this far). When a post is eligible for flagging because it exceeded the threshold set by each individual user, accounts are randomly selected from the pool of enabled users to cast a single flag each, up to a maximum of three per post so that we never unilaterally nuke something. (For this reason, accounts with moderator privileges on a site aren't selected to cast automatic spam flags, and only one flag is cast on sites with a deletion threshold of 3 flags.)

### What are our safety checks?

We designed the entire system with accuracy and sanity checks in mind. Our design collaborations are available for your browsing pleasure ([RFC 1](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Bg0u4oY9W_skp79wSnyQWttUIBH8WV46JELDGJ7Bixo/edit), [RFC 2](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1voGyl3BUA1JHJ0pR2Mf9E5-wmIDUFC1G8HcThiS7B1k/edit), and [RFC 3](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Nu2U0uFbmHpb3v61WyBxjYNK34n5tFWAPYtvu13ZQCw/edit#heading=h.9nvcibv3gama)). The major things that make this system safe and sane are:

- We give users a choice as to how accurate they want to be with their automatic flags. Before casting any flags, we check that the preferences the user has set result in a spam detection accuracy of over 99.5%<sup>1</sup> over a sample of at least 1000 posts. Remember, the current accuracy of humans is 85.7% on SO and network wide it is 95.4%.
- We do not unilaterally spam nuke a post, regardless of how sure we are it is spam. This means that a human *must* be involved to finish off a post, even on the few sites with lower spam thresholds.
- We’ve designed the system to be tolerant of faults - if there’s a malfunction anywhere in the system, any user with access to SmokeDetector can immediately halt all automatic flagging - this includes all network moderators. If this happens, it needs a system administrator to step in to re-enable flags.
- We've discussed this with a community manager and have their [blessing](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35437121#35437121) on the project.

### Results

We have been casting an average of 60-70 automatic flags per day for over two months, for a total of just over 6000 flags network wide. These flags were cast by 22 different users. In that time, we've had [four](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/flagging/logs?filter=fps) false positives. We would like to be able to automatically cancel these particular cases. This isn't possible though, so we've created a feature request to [retract flags via the API](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288120/allow-retracting-flags-from-the-api). In the meantime, the flags are either manually retracted by the user or declined by a moderator.

[image: Weights and Accuracy]

The above graph plots the weight of the reasons against its overall volume of reports and accuracy. As minimum weight increases, accuracy (yellow line and rightmost Y-axis) and total reports (blue line) on the left-hand scale increase. The green line represents the total number of reports (possible spam posts), and the blue line the number of true positives, which are verified by [user feedback](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/SmokeDetector/wiki/Feedback-Guidance).

[image: Automatic Flags per day]

This shows the number of posts we've automatically flagged per day over the last month. The jump on February 15th, is due to increasing the number of automatic flags from 1 per post to 3 per post. You can see a live version of this graph on [metasmoke's autoflagging page](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/flagging).

[image: Spam Hours]

Spam arrives on Stack Exchange in waves. It is easy to see the time of day that many spam reports come in. The hours, above, are UTC time. The busiest spam times of day are the 8 hour block between 4 am and noon. We have affectionately named this "spam hour" in the chat room.

[image: Average Time to Deletion]

Our goal is to delete spam quickly and accurately. The graph shows the time it takes for a reported spam post to be removed from the network. This section has three trend lines that show these averages. The first, red section is when we were simply reporting the posts to chatrooms and all flags had to come from users. You can see we are pretty constant in the time it takes to remove spam during this period. It took, on average, just over five minutes to get a post removed.

The green trend line is when we were issuing a single automatic flag. At implementation, we eliminated a full minute from time to deletion and after a month we'd eliminated two full minutes compared to no automatic flags.

The last section, the orange, is when we implemented three automatic flags to most sites. This was rolled out last week, but it's already had a dramatic improvement on the time to deletion. We are seeing between 1 and 2 minutes to time to deletion.

As mentioned above, spam arrives in waves. The dashed and dotted lines on the graph show the average deletion time during these two different time periods. The dashed lines show deletion time during 4 am and noon UTC, and the dotted lines show the rest of the 24 hour period. An interesting thing this graph shows is that time to deletion during spam hour was higher when we didn't cast any automatic flags. It was removed faster outside of spam hour. That reversed when we started issuing a single auto-flag. The spam hour time to deletion is slightly lower than the average. Comparing the two time periods though, time to deletion during non-spam hour at the end of the non-flagging time period and the end of the single flag period are roughly the same.

We'll update these in a few weeks too, to better show the trend we are seeing with three automatic flags.

### Discussion

We are confident in SmokeDetector and the three years of history it has. We've had many talented developers assist us over the years and many more users have provided feedback to improve our detection rules. Let us know what you want us to elaborate on, features you're wondering about or would like to see added, or things we might have missed in the process or the tooling. Take a look at the [feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288120/allow-retracting-flags-from-the-api) we'd really like Stack Exchange to consider so that we can further improve this system (and some of the other community built systems). We'll have [Charcoal members](https://charcoal-se.org/people.html) hanging around and answering your questions. Alternatively, feel free to drop into [Charcoal HQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq) and have a chat.

---

<sup>1</sup> As of 2018-03-05, the accuracy threshold is 99.75%, instead of 99.5%.

Comment: /me is leaving a comment here so I'm pingable. I'm one of those elusive "system administrators" this talks about.

Comment: Good job everyone! Looks amazing. Smokey itself is already *fantastic*, and the automated flagging looks *neat*! I hope that the proposed change to the API makes it sooner than later.

Comment: "An interesting thing this graph shows is that time to deletion during spam hour was higher when we didn't cast any automatic flags. It was removed faster outside of spam hour." - Guessing this correlates with the time zones that moderators tend to be active, which is something [we've seen before](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309186/why-did-this-spam-live-so-long/309209#309209) when it comes to how long spam lives when flagged.

Comment: What precisely does an "accuracy of `P%`" in spam-flagging mean? For Smokey it's probably the percentage of flags raised (earlier of reports) on posts that were subsequently deleted as spam. But for the human users? Have you exact numbers of spam flags raised and data on the subsequent fate of the posts?

Comment: @DanielFischer, Those numbers/percentages were provided by a community manager. That stat means that of all the spam posts raised, X% were deleted as spam. On Stack Overflow, 85% of the posts flagged as spam were deleted as spam. Across the rest of the network, 95% of the posts flagged as spam were deleted as such.

Comment: Thanks, Andy. So more or less exact numbers. (Though if the number is about the _posts_, the actual flagging stats are probably better, since mistakenly spam-flagged posts tend to only get one flag [and frivolously spam-flagged posts only get more than one flag if the flagger uses socks], while actual spam usually gets several user flags.)

Comment: Charcoal team: excellent work!  Thank you for all the effort you've put into this (and will continue to put in).  This is freaking *awesome*.

Comment: And I'm very happy to see a public post about it here!

Comment: @JasonC [This?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286578/count-of-daily-spam-being-prevented/286615#286615) or [this?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228043/would-anyone-care-for-some-processed-meat-like-substance-with-a-gelatinous-glaze)

Comment: Isn't information like this helping the spammers evade detection? Kinda like those empty repos on Github with a readme that is just one huge advertisement for a commercial service with a few fake issues evade Github's cleanup?

Comment: @user3791372, As a general rule, spammers are lazy. Very few spammers will read this or dig into it more. The few that do are the ones that were already actively working to avoid detection anyway.

Comment: What is the overlap between human and bot spam flags?

Comment: What do you mean by the overlap, @ShiranDror?

Comment: You showed the percent of posts flagged by users and accepted by moderators (95.4%) and that the bot accurately flags (99.5%). How many of these posts were flagged both by the bot and users? @ArtOfCode

Comment: All of them, @Shiran. We only cast 3 flags on a post at maximum, and it takes 6 flags to remove a post - so the other 3 flags are cast by humans.

Comment: @ShiranDror The first number is from long before we started automated flagging, so depending on what you're asking there is no overlap (none of the posts from the first number had flags from the bot, as the bot wasn't running then). If you're asking what proportion in the first number *would have* been flagged, we don't have the necessary data to find that out.

Comment: The 3rd graph is not a hat. That's a boa constrictor digesting an elephant.

Comment: Given that the bot has higher accuracy than the average user, and the bot arrived at that accuracy via feedback from a small group of certain users, it seems like doing something about those incompetent flaggers with a FallibleHumanFlaggerDetector is the next logical step. :P

Comment: This would be cool except for the fact that I JUST LOST 20 LBS IN LESS THAN 2 WEEKS WITH THIS NEW DIET!  Click [HERE](http://www.kalrissanrotts.com/Lizbeth%20dec%2010%2007.jpg) to learn more!

Comment: @billynoah -1, your spam is too grammatically correct

Comment: The description of the first graph seems wrong - the *green* line is the total amount of reports, the *blue* line is the amount of true positives, and the number of reports *decreases* as the minimum weight increases.

Comment: @JacobRaihle thanks for pointing that out, you can blame Jon Ericson for editing in the wrong info :)

Comment: Amazing job, well done! It is probably worth explaining the reason for using three flags. I assume it is from [What are the “spam” and “rude or abusive” (offensive) flags, and how do they work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035/209901): _3 flags on a question (spam or rude or abusive): question is banished from the front page and all question lists except search results_.

Comment: @fedorqui actually, we didn't think it through it that much, we just wanted to halve the number of spam flags required :) However, what you've linked there does reinforce our decision to go with 3 flags

Comment: Great system & write up.  One question; if SE are onboard with this, why do you need real user's accounts to flag things; couldn't they give Smokey an unrestricted account; or if that's problematic give it a few hundred designated accounts.  That seems safer as it's then clear what's done by the bot vs a human, and avoids any risk of future misuse of this privilege (not that you would, but when talking of spam and security that option should be taken into account).

Comment: Who the hell writes at 36pt?

Comment: @JohnLBevan, Everything we do is done via the [API](http://api.stackexchange.com/). If there is a major problem, SE has the ability to see what is done using our application key. As for the unrestricted access, that seems more dangerous because *someone* needs to be able to use those credentials. Since Smokey is run by community members and not SE itself (like the Community User), that would mean a user has moderator (or higher) level access. We've been careful to build the system to not allow users with diamonds that ability to flag spam on their sites. We want to keep a human in the loop.

Comment: Thanks @Andy; is there any argument against having 100 dedicated Smokey "normal user" bot accounts?

Comment: @JohnLBevan The maintenance of such a network would be challenging. We'd need multiple accounts for every site on the network (plus managing that every time a public beta launched) plus the required reputation needed to flag on each site. We'd spend more time managing the accounts than we would fighting spam.

Comment: Thanks @Andy; agreed that without SE explicitly contributing to further the automation of Smokey (i.e. by creating several accounts with a fixed level of reputation across all sites) that makes sense.

Comment: Is this post spam?

Comment: Did Smokey mark this post as spam?  If not, it is broken.

Comment: @Andy Getting a routing error on https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/flagging/run_ocs. Also looks like rails is left in dev mode. It should've been a 404 instead of traces.

Comment: @Mahesh we're in prod mode, but with traces turned on for debugging. Your link is a POST route only, so GET requests result in routing errors.

Comment: If you're so good at spotting spam why are you asking reviewers to do it as well, in review audits?

Comment: @EJP Because the whole purpose of review audits is to test whether you are paying attention ... and in any case there is no link between review audits and  Charcoal ...

Comment: [“Once they became self-modifying, spam-filters and spam-bots got into a war to see which could act more human, and since their failures invoked a human judgement about whether their material were convincingly human, it was like a trillion Turing-tests from which they could learn. From there came the first machine-intelligence algorithms, and then my kind.”](http://www.flurb.net/1/doctorow.htm)

Comment: @EJP We're not affiliated with Stack Exchange; none of us are SE staff, and this is a community project - we have nothing to do with review audits.

Comment: Why is RFC 3 so much prettier than the first two? Did somebody drink too much coffee that night?

Comment: @JasonC I think someone picked a theme for #3 while the others just used the google docs blank theme

Comment: @Andy : are you sure your bot is definitely unaffected by the poodle human facial recognition syndrome ? Or more recently [the semi‑trailer truck being recognized as a road sign](https://electrek.files.wordpress.com/2016/06/tesla-truck-accident-31.jpg). [I know myself](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utilisateur:Ytrezq) than even in the case of spell checking and getting better than human accuracy, bots will always do errors than human never do. In my case my actions were seen as deliberately harmful.

Comment: Every system is going to have false positives. To reduce that, we require humans to cast flags too.

Comment: @user2284570 You're right. And while we do take multiple precautions to avoid false positives being deleted (humans must flag, report must hit multiple reasons to be autoflagged, etc), there is always going to be some false positives. As we said in the post, if you'd like to see us retract flags, please go vote for [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288120/allow-retracting-flags-from-the-api) [feature-request].

Comment: Just delete posts with the word "diet" to catch 90% (95%?) of the spam?

Comment: @ArtOfCode I got that from following your wizard. Looks like the wizard's button was just a plain link and sent a get request.

Comment: @Mahesh mind throwing an issue on the metasmoke [repo](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/metasmoke), so I remember to check on that?

Comment: @Rudolf I haven't taken a look at data, but off the top of my head, spam containing diet makes up a small proportion of what constitutes spam that SE sites get, and there are quite a lot of posts on, for instance, Health.SE and Biology.SE that use this legitimately. We all wish it were that simple. :)

Comment: @RudolfL.Jelínek To put M.A.R's comment in perspective, querying metasmoke, only ~2.900 / 45.000 spam posts we've caught so far contain "diet" [Source](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&title=&body=diet&username=&why=&site=&feedback=&reason=&user_rep_direction=%3E%3D&user_reputation=0&commit=Search)

Comment: @Mahesh I'm seeing a `data-method="post"` on that button. It shouldn't have been changed in the last 24 hours; I'd be interested to see what HTML you're seeing.

Comment: [Obligatory xkcd comic](https://xkcd.com/810/).

Comment: Just seems a bit gross that this whole thing lives outside SE, and has to appropriate human accounts in order to act. But hey, if you're willing to work in those conditions...

Comment: @SteveBennett Failing SE giving us special treatment in this regard, thats all we can do. Charcoal is a community effort, not affiliated with SE. So we have to operate within the boundaries of normal users, largely. We're also not "appropriating" human accounts in order to act, the users explicitly give us their permission to do so.

Comment: @DavidPostill So why can't something **useful** be used as an audit, instead of a pointless spam check? There is a cognitive dissonance here. Reviewers are being asked to waste time to prove that they aren't wasting time.

Comment: @EJP I'm not entirely sure what you're saying here. The whole point of review audits is to check whether or not you're being accurate with your reviewing. If review audits were always spam, than robo-reviewers would know to always click spam so that they don't get caught. Anyway, as David said eariler: review audits have nothing to do with Charcoal or SmokeDetector.

Comment: Can SmokeDetector be set up to detect and reject invalid spam flags? The vast majority of spam flags I see as moderator on SO are on posts that are not spam; in fact, usually there's no mention of any site, product or anything like that. For some reason [users regularly flag nonsense as "spam"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/287278/166442), which wastes moderators' time. If it can detect spam, then the reverse is also true which can be used to warn users when they try to flag non-spam as spam with a message like "This doesn't look like spam - are you sure there is advertising here?".

Comment: @Bohemian I'm not sure that's possible, since I don't think any such tool exists in the API. We can't get data for flags on a post.

Comment: @M.A.R. I meant to engage it during the flagging process, to stop inappropriate spam flagging during the flagging process

Comment: @Boh but for that we need to see who flagged something, no?

Comment: @M.A.R. No. Analyze *in real time* the current post which is in the process of being flagged as spam to verify that it indeed looks like spam and challenge the user who is flagging to justify the flag if it doesn't look like spam.

Comment: @andy you're all not understanding what I am saying. There is no flag!!! Or flagger!!! Let me spell it out... 1) User think a post is "spam" and clicks "Flag" > "Spam", 2) In real time, a SmokeScreen service is synchronously invoked using an AJAX call from the user's browser to assess the spamminess of said post, 3) if the post is not "spammy" enough, a warning msg "this doesn't look like advertising, are you sure?" is shown. The idea is to intercept the flag as it is being made, not afterwards.

Comment: @Bohemian Makes sense, although it's a job for SE developers, a community project can't do that. And [SE tried](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5807095#5807095) without enough success to implement such a system.

Comment: @Bohemian That's not something we're currently set up to do. I suppose it would be possible, with a bunch of work, but it's not the project's focus and I would think long and hard before doing it. It would also require all users to install a userscript, unless Stack Exchange were willing to do some work on their end too.

Comment: @Magisch Yeah, I guess I don't understand the premise here. You're doing a ton of work for SE. Are they actually unwilling to give you the tools and access you need for your stuff to work better? Why?

Comment: @SteveBennett SE is in a tough spot here. They're very busy, and giving us extra tools takes work on the part of the devs. We try not to steal too much of their attention when it's undue. There are things in the works, but they take time.

Comment: @SteveBennett They're not *unwilling* to help us out with resources and tools, but they don't have a lot of spare developer time to do it with - so, if we can do it ourselves (even if it's not quite optimal), that's often a better way.

Comment: In about 76 active checks on that dashboard, I can see that at least 24 are so far from accurate that they need to be retired.  Probably more than half of them, like any that are less than 95% accurate.

Comment: There is a difference between the posts detected and the posts flagged. Flagged posts are done based on a combination of the reasons you see. Posts fall into multiple categories and it's those multiple categories that determine if a post will be flagged or not. Individual reasons are less accurate on their own.

Comment: Sorry '-1' from me directly, for using the very vague Term "machine" in the Qt Title and not finding a Def about it, through "diagonal reading", I didn't read further although the Qt is certainly very interesting... "System" would sound more appropriate to me..., but would still need to define the "Scope"... (And the Answer is "Yep of course...!", I "do" it myself as (only) Mod on a (small) Tech Forum (for 6 years now), 30% manually and 70% through Bots/Scripts (that I all 100% wrote myself, I don't use any Plug-ins)), Spammers "welcome" if they "behave", the Forum is about Web-Automation...!)

Answer (score 113):

Stack Exchange has its own spam detection and prevention system. If I understand its design goal correctly it prevents spam from even being posted. What SmokeDetector finds are basically the posts that passed their tests.

Two questions:

- Is there any other feedback loop from SmokeDetector to that system, except posts being flagged as Spam? If not, any plans?
- Are there statistics available that show that SpamRam got better by keeping spam out due to the successful efforts of the SmokeDetector and its human slaves?

Comment: SpamRam here is... SE's own spam detection/blocker?

Comment: @TylerH that is what I picked up on how it is called, yes

Comment: (1) Yes. Possibly. We've had discussions with Stack Exchange staff about directly integrating the Smokey system with SE, and we intend to have some more.

Comment: (2) Currently, no - but SpamRam only works with IPs, not with post text like Smokey does.

Comment: There isn't any other feedback from SmokeDetector to SpamRam specifically. Removing a post via spam flags does feed it though, so indirectly, this is helping. There have been tentative discussions on if it'd be possible to integrate all/part of smoke detector.

Comment: To expand on AOC last comment: "SpamRam works with ip reputation and feedback"

Comment: SmokeDetector is awesome! A few incredible community members got together and created it independently of Stack Overflow's internal spam-fighting efforts. It so happens that building some connections between our systems and Smokey is something I've been (very slowly) thinking about exploring, as ArtOfCode mentioned. No solid plans yet though. As for SpamRam, we don't really talk about it much publicly. True, the odds of spammers coming here to look up info on us are low, but if one does, that's maybe the one we'd actually need to be worried about.

Comment: A spam detection system that can be bypassed by knowing how it works is fundamentally broken. It's like the school tests that use a corpus of questions that students have to answer, and can be bypassed by mere memorizing of a sufficient number of questions. We have known forever that this doesn't work without placing silly restrictions like people being unable to get their tests back (argh!) or the inability to discuss how a spam filter is designed. The design of a test, or a spam filter, must start with the assumption that it's all public and available for anyone. Then it'll work by design.

Comment: @KubaOber In theory, knowing our filters could let people bypass them. In practice, spammers aren't that smart and we can react and add new filters as necessary.

Comment: @Magisch At the moment, the filters are nowhere near state of the art. It's mostly a bunch of regexes from what I see. This is not scalable and can't be but a temporary solution.

Comment: @KubaOber Our entire project is based on pattern detection. Other then adding more patterns and more clever patterns, there isn't really much else in scope here. We're not machine learning experts, unfortunately. If you have some suggestions or want to discuss this further, drop into [charcoal hq in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq)

Comment: It's been scaling for three years now just fine - and the main bottleneck is human fatigue doing the actual flagging anyways.

Comment: @KubaOber Nope, no state of the art stuff here. But that doesn't matter - it works, and has worked for the past three years, and I don't see any reason why it won't continue to work.

Comment: Of course, it is a nice pragmatic approach. Right now the humans do the explicit work of pattern updates. To reduce the tedium, humans could do the work of flagging spam, and the machine can figure the patterns much better than us. I'm no machine learning expert either, though, so I'm not much help - I mostly consume libraries other people write :)

Comment: Unfortunately, neither are any of us, @KubaOber. My own attempt at ML failed miserably, and others have suffered similar fates. It's something we'd like to do, but none of us have the expertise necessary.

Comment: In Meta, questions are answers and answers are questions!

Answer (score 72):

> We determined we can beat those numbers and eliminate spam from Stack Overflow **and the rest of the network even faster.**

(Emphasis mine)

What, if any, work have you done to ensure the robustness of SmokeDetector (SD) across different sites in the network, given that they have broadly different scopes and topics? For example, you've finely tuned SD to detect when something is spammy on Stack Overflow, but how dependent on "sharing links that have nothing to do with programming" is SD's codebase?

Is it a matter of flipping a few switches and adding half a dozen phrases to an array in order for it to work on Biology.SE, where things like medicine names might be mentioned regularly, or Aviation.SE, where airlines might get mentioned frequently? (I picked those two because airline tickets and pills are two common spam topics) Or will it require a non-trivial customization per site?

Comment: We've run across the entire network since its inception - all of the accuracy numbers you see in the above post *are* network wide. Some reasons are tuned for specific sites, some are disabled on some sites. It's a fun balancing game, but we've gotten pretty good at it.

Comment: For example, [here](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/SmokeDetector/blob/master/findspam.py#L428) is some code which checks for health-related spam, but it works only on some sites of the network which are often targeted. And [here](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/SmokeDetector/blob/master/findspam.py#L434) another 'filter' which is active on all but a few sites which are likely to yield many false positives.

Comment: @Undo Thanks, that wasn't clear after reading; the post only mentions Stack Overflow specifically when talking about SD's flagging behavior.

Comment: @Undo And to focus on that topic a bit, do you have numbers per site? I'm curious if there are any sites with 100% accuracy, and also curious what the site w/ the lowest accuracy is.

Comment: [Ask Patents](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/search?utf8=✓&title=&body=&username=&why=&site=172) is probably the worst site, with currently only 64% accuracy. But remember that those posts generally won't be autoflagged, only when they reach a certain threshold.

Comment: But AP is just... weird, so that's not exactly surprising.

Comment: @Glorfindel "but remember" Where might I have seen the threshold before if I am to remember it? Are you talking about each user's individual threshold? If that's the case, does that mean users set their own threshold preference before the bot can flag as them? If so, what if there is a user who sets their threshold to, say, 60% while everyone else sets theirs higher? Are the settings published? It wouldn't be random in that case... SD would always use the 60% account and two others.

Comment: @TylerH sorry, I should have elaborated. My link shows all posts *reported* by SmokeDetector, often detected for just a single reason. Autoflags will only be cast if a post is detected for multiple reasons, and they need to be 'effective' reasons, too. You can't set a threshold resulting in lower than 99.5% accuracy.

Comment: @Glorfindel Thanks for the info!

Comment: It looks a bit tricky to apply. As in, I'm assuming I'd have to install Linux first? And then run this in the background on my PC?

Comment: @SirAdelaide You don't need to do anything, we (Charcoal) host the bot (see [here](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/status) for current location) and metasmoke (which does all the flagging), all you need to do is sign up and allow us to use your account for flagging. We then use the SE API to flag the posts. But yes, the bot does run on a form of linux/mac, due to compatiablility issues with bash and git which we use extensively. Feel free to drop into [Charcoal HQ](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq) if you have any more questions

Comment: @Undo how does that balancing work with newly-created beta sites?

Comment: @NathanMerrill In practice, newly created beta sites have extremely low traffic anyway. Since our regexes are balanced for ~160 sites already, new ones *usually* don't fall much outside of what we've already seen. Usually, the only times we need to tune explicitly are for health-focused sites. We catch a lot of skin care spammers across the network, but the nature of those patterns see high false positive rates on health sites. It's always caught quickly and dealt with in a thirty-second-deploy cycle or two.

Answer (score 23):

While Charcoal HQ and your GitHub and website have been publicly accessible in the past, posts like these will increase your visibility across the Stack Exchange network and maybe even reach the top search results in Google. While most of the spammers seem quite dumb (it seems they can't even write correct English sentences), aren't you afraid that this will lead to the more crafty spammers discovering ways to escape detection by SmokeDetector, for example by including their spam links in comments (to their own posts)?

Comment: Don't give them any ideas :P (jk). That's actually an interesting proposal.

Comment: Spammers aren't usually that clever. We do see some people attempting to spam in comments, but not that many. We also see spammers occasionally posting apparently OK answers and then editing in spam later. Pretty much all of these attempts fail as people notice and flag them.

Comment: No, I'm not concerned. Very few spammers will read this or look at the website or source code. The few that do are the ones that were already actively working to avoid detection anyway.

Comment: Also note that the Charcoal sites will *not* have their SEO pushed up from this - SE specifically makes that not happen.

Comment: General rule: spammers are dumb. You can count on them to be dumb. Being intelligent takes *time*, which could be spent posting more spam.

Comment: Remember that comments are usually not indexed by google, so spammers won't win that much by it

Comment: We've seen cases where the spam links were put in comments instead of the question body. It wasn't very successful. If we can keep raising the bar for spammers, to the point where they have to make meaningful contributions... [Mission accomplished](https://xkcd.com/810/).

Comment: @Mego, [be careful what you wish for](http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/questions/2436/how-can-this-site-stop-why-do-x-still-exist-questions).

Comment: This seems like it might be a interesting challenge to implement.

Comment: Regarding *'correct English sentences'* - there's a theory that spammers/scammers are [using mistakes deliberately](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/96154/47832) in order to turn away anybody who is unlikely to be  gullible enough to follow through with it.

Comment: @ArtOfCode, there are exceptions, though. I've dealt with a spammer who obviously read the spamassassin-users mailing list. I posted rules for blocking his spam; he shut down for a day or so, and came back with modified spam that didn't hit those rules.

Comment: @andybalholm Sure, there are always exceptions. But the *vast* majority of spammers here are dumb - we seem to cultivate an especially dumb breed of spammer, actually.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:BEANS

Comment: I don't think most spammers will due this due to the rule of diminishing returns.

Comment: My first thought, was that it's not in principle to decide what is Spam unequivocally - since it can be crafted arbitrarily close to a genuine message - even so, the linked-to site (or keywords they use to direct you there via Google) will be noticeable / visible as Spam !

Comment: @FerryBig ..., => Oops...!!: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Remember+that+comments+are+usually+not+indexed+by+google%2C+so+spammers+won%27t+win+that+much+by+it%22

Answer (score 18):

I understand the question was rhetorical, but let me answer anyway.

The English Wikipedia has had such a machine for a while, mostly ClueBotNG, which follows some rules and a bit of learning. Some summaries are available at

- https://github.com/DamianZaremba/cluebotng
- http://www.bbc.com/news/magazine-18892510
- [*Profiling vandalism in Wikipedia* review](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Research:Newsletter/2016/August#Ethics_researcher:_Vandal_fighters_should_not_be_allowed_to_see_whether_an_edit_was_made_anonymously), also mentions other systems
- http://wikipapers.referata.com/wiki/ClueBot

For more Wikimedia wikis, a similar but more general system is active since 2015, focused on providing editors with the best guesses machine-learning can make about the productivity of a contribution: [*Artificial intelligence service "ORES" gives Wikipedians X-ray specs to see through bad edits*](https://blog.wikimedia.org/2015/11/30/artificial-intelligence-x-ray-specs/).

Answer (score 12):

That's genuinely terrific; congrats to those involved:

Two quick questions: I hope this is directed at the right folks.

1. How does it compare to Gmail, just very roughly, in filtering effectiveness?
2. Can I now go back to PhysicsSE and say we have a possible way, sometime in the future, to filter homework questions (which are worse than spam, in some opinions)?

Apologies if I missed these questions in the previous responses. Just tell me that, and I will have a mooch myself through this post.

Comment: I'm not sure it *can* be compared to Gmail, really - SmokeDetector is tailored so specifically to the stuff we get on SE that I'm not sure direct comparison is possible/useful. That said, we see a *very* large percentage of any spam that gets past the SE-native filters.

Comment: As for (2), no. SmokeDetector is tailored to spam, and its method of detection (regex) is not easy to adapt to other purposes - we have enough spam tests to reach the top of the One World Trade Center, and recreating that for homework would take far too long to be useful. It's also out of scope for the main Smokey project, though anyone is of course welcome to fork it for their own use.

Comment: Thanks, I use regex in php and it can be hit and (usually miss). All the best

Comment: No worries, happy to answer questions. If there are enough samples of stuff, anything can be identified eventually. What I wonder about homework questions is the variety - homework doesn't seem like something that would be the same (or extremely similar) every time, unlike spam.

Comment: It's a continuous issues, you could be dissing/ discouraging the next Einstein , but at the same time some users just ignore all warning, which is annoying. I don't have an agenda one way or another,  but the PSE commununity periodically goes through cycles of questions that appear just before exams. I think every possible procedure has been discussed, and discussed....

Comment: Yep, it's not an easy one to deal with. I'm not sure there's much Smokey can do to help with it, but if you do ever come up with an automated solution I'd like to hear about it.

Comment: SmokeDetector *is* a great platform for seeing everything that comes into a site - you could definitely fork it and strip out the unnecessary bits, then add whatever logic you'd use to detect these. But yes, it is out of scope for Charcoal.

Comment: There is a [stackapp](http://stackapps.com/questions/7183/firealarm-detecting-low-quality-questions-with-machine-learning) developed and running in [sobotics](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111347/sobotics), for detecting poor quality questions on Stack Overflow. You can certainly fork it, and make one for Physics.SE.

Comment: @BhargavRao thanks very much for that

Comment: @AlternativeFacts I'm one of the developers of FireAlarm. If you are interested in this thing, and want to run it on Physics.SE, please visit [this chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123602/firealarm-development) where you can get further details.

Comment: IMO, homework isn't really comparable to spam. Spam is generally always negative, and posters of spam don't tend to be well-meaning. However, while there's definitely annoying and exasperating homework-question askers, there's also perfectly polite students who are coming to a useful resource to ask for help in explaining something they don't understand. SE websites are large collections of very knowledgeable people. If a particular user is abusing the site (i.e. frequently posting asking others to solve specific homework problems) then that should be handled on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: @AbigailFox Hi , I do take your point and I have a comment above that I hope  reflects your comments. I love it when someone really has a go at trying a problem, as I can see myself (as a self study person) in the same position, but not so much when the OP ignores all the rules and  basically demands an answer, that gets my goat a bit. It's hardly ever a particular repeating user on PSE (in my experience) as they get the message the first time they post  ,it's rather lots of people who are often desperate as their exam is a day away. But I was just curious when I saw the new filter.

Comment: @Countto10 Yes, that's for sure annoying. It's just awfully specific and difficult for a robot (I'd imagine) to discern. Either it's very clearly spam-like, or it falls in a grey area where a human notices that it's an obvious attempt to get a specific problem solved for the OP. I just think these should be human-handled and not auto flagged, because posters of these questions tend to be (at least marginally) more well-meaning than posters of true spam.

Comment: @AbigailFox. Without meaning to take up your time, my "solution" is to beef up the warning, **no attempt means no answer** , and have a dedicated, in both senses of the word, moderator to look at the questions and have the power to delete the bad ones immediately with a post to the OP saying why. If the OP is determined, he/she will adjust to post a better question. Rgds

Comment: @ArtOfCode.    Just for info, your next project http://www.bbc.com/news/technology-39063863

Comment: @Countto10 There's a [stackapp](http://stackapps.com/q/7001/42239) for that too! And strangely, the [owner of that app requested for a perspectiveAPI key](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/111347?m=35806270#35806270) around 24 hrs before your comment. (Spooky stuff, right?)

Answer (score 11):

**Has there been any thought about a quarantine area?**

Give the incredible accuracy you have reached, I am wondering if it would be worth switching tactics here: instead of posting by default and deleting later, I am wondering if it would make sense instead to check first, and only post "immediately" if the check is OK, putting the dubious stuff in a quarantine area (a review queue?) where users with the privilege to vote could cancel the bot decision if it is unfounded.

This way, detected spam would not even appear on the front-page (and be indexed by Google) ever, decreasing the benefits spammers gain from it further.

Comment: In theory this sounds like a good idea, until you look at the number of posts that are created across the network daily. With that volume, the review queue would be overwhelmed in a matter of hours, unfortunately.

Comment: @Andy: Wait, the OP says "We have been casting an average of 60-70 automatic flags per day for over two months", how would 60-70 posts per day overwhelm the queue in a matter of hours?

Comment: Assuming I understood your post correctly, those 60-70 flags only accounts for the bad posts that make it through SE's own filters. If we are going to quarantine stuff before posting so that it can be reviewed, we have to account for all the *good* posts too. Those would overwhelm the review queue. We see orders of magnitude more "good/ok" posts than we do spam. SmokeDetector isn't early enough in the process to prevent posts from being made. It would have to be integrated into the SE post process.

Comment: @Andy I don't think you're understanding their suggestion. From what I understand the idea is: run it against smokey before the post is sent to the site. If it fails, quarantine it. Otherwise post it. Other than requiring SE dev integration that doesn't sound like a bad idea. Certainly shouldn't fill up the review queues.

Comment: Although at this point I'm not sure it's worth it since anything smokey detects is almost instantly deleted anyway.

Comment: @Andy: I am not suggesting putting *everything* in quarantine. Citing myself: *I am wondering if it would make sense instead to check first, and only post "immediately" if the check is OK, putting the dubious stuff in a quarantine area (a review queue?)* => only the dubious stuff should go to quarantine, which is 60-70 posts per day according to the OP.

Comment: @ɥʇǝS: There's a window of a few minutes where those posts are polluting the front page AND get indexed. It would be more pleasant for users if they were never on the front page and less attractive for spammers if they were never indexed.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Actually, stuff smokey detects rarely lasts more than 2 minutes and since auto flagging came online I haven't seen it last even 1.

Comment: I misunderstood then. Right now, it's not possible to prevent the posting from taking place. But, [we've had some discussions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291301/can-a-machine-be-taught-to-flag-spam-automatically/291432?noredirect=1#comment945782_291303) with SE on how we can better integrate. I'll bring it up when we talk to them next.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: Since it's all nofollowed anyway I don't see any rational sense in which it really could be much less attractive to spammers.

Comment: @NathanTuggy: Good point, I guess they don't even realize it.

Answer (score 4):

Do you think you'll incorporate more advanced machine learning (like neural networks) at any point?

Comment: Entirely possible. We've thrown around ideas before about doing some kind of machine learning.

Comment: We've tried various forms of machine learning, but due to the lack of our experience in that field we have found that regex-based searching is more effective.

Comment: I did write a Naive Bayes ML version of Smokey a while back, making use of our existing data for classification sets - but either I don't have enough experience with ML to do it right, or it just plain didn't work, because its accuracy was no better than just guessing.

Answer (score 4):

Only one remark: [What will you do when spammers train their bots to make automated constructive and helpful comments?](https://xkcd.com/810/)

Otherwise, keep up the great work!

Seriously: Directly, actively preventing spam from being posted in the first place (error: unable to post this, because of spam) might cause spammers to quicker work around the system. One should assume that spammers feel less motivated working around a prevention system, when they actually still *think*, they get their messages delivered. Therefore, I like this pragmatic and successful approach!

Comment: This is actually a pretty core part of why SE is so spam free. The spammers think they can post semi-freely, what they don't check back to is that their post sometimes gets canned in <10s.

Answer (score -17):

### Why not push this a bit further? Would it not be even more transparent and effective?

As you have demonstrated and I had no doubt, programs are more efficient than humans.

Currently you are using other users' flags to reduce the number of humans needed to nuke the post with the objective to decrease effort and time to deletion (which will have, as a benefit, less interest to spam SE and less effort from SE users to flag it).

While this is great and again I have no doubt that the algorithms used are more precise and effective than any human, the problem of responsibility remains, four normal users stating "the bot flagged for me", a fewer normal users deciding if the post should be nuked.

**Push it further! It will be more transparent and effective**

What I suggest is to use moderator accounts on the different sites, to directly spam-delete the post.

If these moderators (as we) trust the algorithms and the statistics, let them use their account, the result will be:

1. Responsibility of who deleted the post.
2. Possibility for who was responsible to restore reputation and post if something goes wrong (it's the moderator)
3. Increased efficiency of the spam blocking system. If we and moderators trust it, let's immediately delete these posts without using "socket" users.

You would only need volunteer moderators on major SE sites and since many moderators from different SE sites are already involved in this, I think it will not be a problem.

These moderators need to agree to use the account and are ready to check what have been deleted. In case of any harm is done, they have the privilege to restore the situation.

Comment: Moderators are ATM not allowed to autoflag on their sites because we never want to unilaterally nuke something. We want all of Charcoal to see if it needs action - having a mod nuke would negate that.

Comment: That's a step we're not willing to take yet. Sending flags from mortals allows us to send signal to the system; sending flags from a moderator account would be a whole new step. If we were to do that, it'd be extremely limited in scope and with a lot of staff consultation.

Comment: @Mithrandir I know this, what I'm stating is use **moderator account**, we trust Smokey and we trust them, they can check later if something goes wrong they can fix it, I can't really see the sense in just reducing flags need for a few users.

Comment: @Undo A small step for man, but a giant leap for SE, honestly I can't really see the difference from using 1 moderator account and 4-5 auto flags and 2-3 flags from chat room

Comment: @PetterFriberg Main difference is that using a moderator account could nuke a post within a few seconds of it being posted, bringing a 100-rep penalty and SpamRam fun - all without human eyes ever needing to be set upon it.

Comment: @PetterFriberg We *may* expand the system, but we're not going to expand from 3 flags to moderator flags - it'll be staged. If 3 flags goes well, maybe we move to 4. If that goes well, maybe 5, and maybe on to 6. We'll be talking to Stack Exchange staff throughout that process, and moderator flags aren't even something we'd consider until we're ready to use 6 flags anyway.

Comment: I admire and understand that you are cautious, but I'm not convinced that the right way to go is to reduce flags for other users, instead I would like to see go ahead to nuke high probability spam post directly (I bet you are at least as precis as spam ram), anyway fantastic work.

Comment: As a moderator, I feel that it is inappropriate to give someone else (even an automated system) access to my moderator privileges to take any sort of action on my behalf. As a moderator, my flags are immediate with few checks.

Comment: I don't think giving access to the moderator account to a bot is a good idea. It might even be a violation of the moderator agreement, it certainly is if non-moderators have access to the bot. Moderator accounts have access to PII, if a bot were to cast binding flags, it should happen via an SE-provided API that doesn't require giving out the full access a real moderator has.

Comment: @MadScientist the flagging api is always the same, the only difference would be that the flag is binding (nuked as spam with 1 flag) and traceable to 1 moderator (hence responsibility of 1 moderator).

Comment: @PetterFriberg It's still traceable and accountable now - it's just the responsibility of 3 people, across 3 flags. That's no different to what moderators are used to already.

Comment: @ArtOfCode sure and considering the hit rate they will not risk flag ban, just wanted to point out that it's enough to comment out line 109 in your current code and moderators flags could be used on there home site.

Comment: @PetterFriberg That's not something we're interested in doing, at least not for a while yet.

Comment: Fair enough, just wanted to state that I would prefer a similar solution. Nice work @ArtOfCode

Comment: I believe that the only way to do this in a way that make sense, we should block them outright instead of using some user account to flag.

Comment: Another solution could be to make Smokey employee if it has better or same false positive rate as SpamRam, but ok this is a start and it surely is a great project

Comment: @PetterFriberg no, we will never ask to give Smokey employee access, nor will SE ever let us. It would effectively allow anyone with access to the account (including non-mods such as me) to use employee-only tools (nuke every question ever created? why not?)

Comment: Just let employee handle the account  (changing the password to the account).

Comment: Letting regular users do this is already irresponsible.  Setting accuracy aside, it misrepresents what the user is doing and who or what is doing the flagging.  Another consideration: Flag weight still exists IIRC, just behind-the-scenes -- this allows the user to use a bot to inflate their own trustworthiness in the eyes of the system, giving greater weight to their own manual flags.

Comment: What do you suggest instead, @MatthewRead? Bear in mind that we can't use the bot account itself, because that amounts to the bad sort of sockpuppetry.

Comment: I suggest that you _don't do this_.  Either stick to alerting humans or try to get something officially integrated with SE.

Comment: @MatthewRead The first step in getting something integrated with SE is to prove it can be done without their systems.

Comment: @ɥʇǝS I doubt that.  Regardless, the first step backward is abusing their systems and user account access.  I can't and won't speak for SE, they might totally be OK with this, but it conflicts with everything I know as a mod.

Comment: @MatthewRead A number of Charcoal people are mods, myself included. We've had a chat about this with a CM over several months as its been moving towards implementation, and have been given permission to do this.

Comment: We are also moving towards tighter integration with SE, as Pops said in a comment above somewhere, but that takes both time and developer effort on their part, which is spread thin right now. Both of these options have advantages and disadvantages, but we believe the benefits of getting spam deleted faster outweigh the negatives of this system.

Comment: @MatthewRead I'm actually a little confused as to the nature of your general objection, as SpamRam is essentially already a fully automated post nuking system that you are presumably OK with. Smokey merely expands the spam filter with some extra rules, and as a *bonus* still requires human confirmation unlike the usual spam filter. If Smokey's ruleset were simply integrated into the existing fully automated system it does not seem like you would have the same objection, rather, you would likely appreciate SE improving their existing bot that unilaterally nukes posts (i.e. their spam filters).

Comment: @MatthewRead To address *"this allows the user to use a bot to inflate their own trustworthiness in the eyes of the system, giving greater weight to their own manual flags"*: There are more than 100 people signed up right now. We issue ~230 flags per day. It's load balanced (randomly distributed, actually) across those 100 users, then across a dozen or so high-spam sites. (230/100)/12 is a very small number. It's not going to win you an election.

Comment: I don't see how my comments could possibly be interpreted as being against automation.  _I am against abusing user accounts for this._  It's true that I would have no objection with it being integrated into the system.  "It's not going to win you an election" is a straw man.

Comment: @MatthewRead I am not sure I understand the connection between users opting in to have a limited small number of the flags they would have cast manually be cast automatically instead, and abusing user accounts. (To put it in perspective, the automated system casts about 2 of my flags for me per day total, across the ~100 sites I have an account on, and out of the dozen or so I cast anyways). Can you clarify?

Comment: @MatthewRead chat might be a better venue for this discussion; feel free to drop into [Charcoal HQ](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540) to talk about it. I'd like to understand why you think this is abuse.