# Is there way to register all Stack Exchange Sites in a single click?

Tags: support, login, sign-up

Is there way to register all Stack Exchange Sites with a single click, instead of joining each and every site?

Comment: I think the usability of a Japanese SO account is at least dubious for us, for example.

Comment: There's no SE provided way, and probably for good reason: the sites a user has/has not joined is interesting profiling information in itself.. just because SE isn't evil(?) doesn't mean they aren't watching you ;)

Answer (score 2):

No, there is not. The only way you could achieve that if you would would extent the websites functionality by writing your own (or [searching for an existing](https://stackapps.com/?tab=scripts)) [User Script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Userscript) to achieve that functionality. I wouldn't have high-hopes on having this feature implemented by SE, ever.

Beyond that, I'm very conscious about which site I sign-up for, despite that I joined many sites for reasons of [Spam flagging](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291301/can-a-machine-be-taught-to-flag-spam-automatically) I'm still a few short.

Comment: ... and why would you, anyways?

Comment: What do you mean by "You would have to write your own user script to achieve that."?

Comment: @DonkeyKingandDonkeyKing expanded a bit on what that means

Comment: _What do you mean by "You would have to write your own user script to achieve that."?_ you are the only person with such requirement. So you should write it.