# Awarded 'deputy' badge for helpful flags I haven't raised

Tags: support, flags, flagging-badges

So, I've been awarded the deputy badge on Graphic Design for raising 80 helpful flags.  I'm pretty awesome.

https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/27180/paddy?tab=activity&sort=all

Much as I love my imaginary internet badges, I think I may only have been on Graphic Design once, and certainly I doubt I've raised any helpful flags there at all.  (Or generally been at all helpful).

So what's going on?

Comment: Are you saying you didn't raise any of [these flags](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/27180)? That link is to your flag summary page on the site.

Comment: @Taryn - that's correct, however Glorfindel's answer seems to point in the direction of the reason why.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You've signed up for [Autoflagging](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291301/can-a-machine-be-taught-to-flag-spam-automatically), so these flags have been cast automatically on spam posts reported by the SmokeDetector bot. 
[Here](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/flagging/users/132/logs) is a link to the flags which have been cast in your name.

If you want to opt out of autoflagging, you can do so on your [preferences](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/flagging/preferences) page.

Comment: That's interesting.  I have to say that I honestly don't remember opting into this, but given the state of my memory these days, that doesn't necessarily mean that it hasn't happened.

Comment: @Paddy - It would have been almost a year ago by now, so it's not unreasonable that you'd have forgotten (assuming you signed up because you saw [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291301/294691) while it was featured network-wide).