# A machine can flag spam automatically. Can it do better?

Tags: discussion, flags, spam, robots

> Since this has been posted, we've done a few things:
>
> 1. We now cast *four* flags on posts that pass an accuracy threshold (current 99.9% historical confidence)
> 2. SmokeDetector now casts the **first** flag on all autoflagged posts. That should help address concerns about transparency in the flag queue & on post flag timelines.
> 3. There's [a userscript](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/userscripts/raw/master/sim/sim.user.js) exposing auto flagging activity inline on the post. It's pretty:
>
>    [image]
> 4. We're trying to get an RSS feed of posts deleted with autoflags for chat consumption, but chat RSS is fraught with peril.

**TL;DR:** [Charcoal](https://charcoal-se.org/people) is the organisation behind [SmokeDetector](https://charcoal-se.org/). Since January 2017, [we've been casting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291301/262823) up to 3 flags automatically on posts that our systems are confident are spam. We'd like to increase that to 5 automatic flags on posts we're even *more* certain of to reduce the time spam spends alive on the network.

## Who are you?

Charcoal is a user-run organisation that is primarily responsible for the spam-detecting bot, SmokeDetector. Over the past four years, with the aid of SmokeDetector, we've looked for spam on the Stack Exchange network to flag and destroy manually. In January 2017, with the blessing of Stack Exchange, we started running an "autoflagging" project, wherein our systems automatically cast up to three flags on a post if they're confident that it's spam. If you missed that happening entirely, we wrote a [meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291301/262823) on Meta Stack Exchange - or there's a slightly more concise explanation [on our website](https://charcoal-se.org/flagging).

## How's that been going for you?

Good. We currently have 215 users who have opted into the autoflagging system ([you can sign up too](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/flagging/ocs), if you're interested). We've flagged around 30 000 (29 592) posts, of which the vast majority (29 526) were confirmed spam - that's 99.7% accurate.

## What are you proposing?

We'd like to expand our autoflagging system. At present we cast up to 3 automated flags on posts we're confident are spam; we'd like to increase that number to 5 flags on a subset of those autoflagged posts where we're even more certain they're spam.

### Why?

Just so we're up-front about this: **this is an experiment**. Ultimately, we're trying to do these things:

- Reduce the time that spam spends on the sites before being deleted;
- Lower the number of humans who involuntarily have to see or interact with spam.

Increasing the number of flags we cast automatically on spam should accomplish both of these things:

- Automatic flags are near-instant; manual flags take multiple minutes to be cast - that means that increasing the ratio of automatic to manual flags results in a shorter time before 6 flags accumulate and the spam is deleted.
- Automatic flags are not cast by a human. Fewer humans, therefore, are forced to see/interact with the spam.

The data we have backs this up. In terms of time to deletion, we saw a significant drop in the time it took to delete spam when we started our autoflagging project. Take a look at [this graph from the meta post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obd8v.png) on the subject for an excellent visual representation of that. Before we started autoflagging, spam spent an average of 56 hours per day alive across the network; with autoflagging in place, the average is much less, at around 7 hours per day.

## What would this change mean for sites?

If this change goes ahead, these things are likely to happen:

- It will only take 1 or 2 manual flags from users to [spam-nuke](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035/262823) an autoflagged post, instead of the current 3. Posts that are not autoflagged will, of course, still require 6 flags to nuke.
- There may be an increase in posts spam-nuked entirely by Charcoal members, who may or may not be active on the site.
- You will see a reduction in the time spam spends on the site before being deleted.
- Fewer humans will have to involuntarily see each spam post.

The last two of those are indisputably good things. The first two, however, are more controversial, and are the reason we want to have a discussion here on meta before we make this happen. What follows are the major concerns we've seen, and what we can do about them or why we don't think they're an issue - we'd like to hear your thoughts.

The major thing we're looking for out of this is a reduction in time to deletion. The following graph shows how long spam currently spends alive on the top few sites; we're hoping to see a moderate reduction in the average times, and a significant reduction in the top outliers.

[image]

The following graph is from an experiment we've been running over the past week, casting between 1 and 5 flags randomly on each post matching the settings we're considering.

[image]

In raw numbers, that's this:

```
PostCount  FlagCount  ATTD      StdDev  CommonMax
173        1          191.474   243.63  678.73
166        2          98.7831   127.88  354.55
167        3          69.2814   156.62  382.51
194        4          33.3196   61.46   156.23
177        5          13.5254   12.43   38.39
```

`PostCount` is the sample size; `FlagCount` the number of flags cast on each post in the sample; `ATTD` the average time to deletion, and `CommonMax` is the maximum of a 95% confidence interval. The major takeaway from these stats is that we're likely to see a ~5x drop in the average time to deletion, and a ~10x drop in the outliers.

### Accuracy & false positives

Spam flags are a powerful feature that need some care in applying correctly. This is a concern that came up when we originally built the autoflagging system, so we already have safeguards built in.

- We only flag a post if we're more than 99.75% sure it's spam. (Technically, the *precise* certainty varies by conditions set by the users whose accounts we use, but it's *always* above 99.75% - more detail on that on [our website](https://charcoal-se.org/flagging)).
- If the system breaks down or bugs out and starts flagging things it shouldn't, all Charcoal members and all network moderators have access to a command that immediately halts all flagging activity and requires intervention from a system administrator to re-enable. Outside of testing, that kill-switch has never had to be used.
- We never unilaterally nuke a post. There are currently 3 manual flags required in addition to the automatic flags to nuke a post; this increase proposal still retains *at least* one manual flag.

We also make sure that everything has human oversight at all times. While only 3 humans currently have to manually flag the post, there are always more users than that reviewing the system's decisions and classifications; if a post is flagged that shouldn't have been, we are alerted and can alert the relevant moderators to resolve the issue. Again, this is very rare: over the past year, we've flagged 66 posts that shouldn't have been, compared to 29 592 spam posts (that's 99.7% accurate overall). We allow users to set their own flagging conditions, provided they don't go below our baseline 99.75% certainty. We recommend, however, a higher value that has a certainty of 100.00% - those who set their conditions below that are likely to see more false positives flagged using their account.

This proposal decreases the required manual involvement to nuke a post; to compensate for that lower human-involvement barrier, we will correspondingly increase the required accuracy before casting the extra automatic flags. For example, **we currently require 99.75% accuracy before casting autoflags; we could require 99.9% accuracy for 4 autoflags, and 99.99% accuracy for 5 autoflags**. (For reference, humans are accurate 95.4% of the time, or 87.3% on Stack Overflow - those are stats that [jmac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1933347/jmac) (a former Community Manager) looked up for us last year when we started autoflagging).

In the rare event of a legitimate post getting autoflagged, we also have systems in place to ensure it isn't accidentally deleted and forgotten about. Multiple people review each post we catch, whether it's autoflagged or not, and classify it as spam or not; if an autoflagged post is classified as not-spam, the system posts an alert to chat to let us know. That lets us ping the necessary people to retract their flags, and keep an eye on the post to make sure it doesn't get deleted.

To make it starkly clear how accurate this could be, here's a visualisation:

[image: 300x100 grid of green squares, with one red square near the top]

That's a chronological representation (left-right, top-bottom) of every post that would have been flagged under the settings we're considering for 5 flags, and whether they were spam (green squares) or legitimate (red squares).

### Community agency & involvement

As I said earlier, this proposal reduces the required manual involvement to nuke a post. Since Charcoal members also cast manual flags on top of the automatic flags cast by the system, that's also likely to increase the number of posts that are nuked entirely by Charcoal members, without involvement from users who are active on this site. Some posts already have 6 flags cast on them by Charcoal (including autoflagging and manual flags), but the proportion of posts that applies to is likely to increase.

We don't think this is an issue in terms of subject matter expertise: the spam we see on the Stack Exchange network is broadly the same wherever you go - you don't need any subject matter expertise or activity on a particular site to be able to tell what's spam and what's not. We do, however, recognise that it's possible that a site's community may want to handle its own spam; if that's the case, we're happy to turn the autoflagging system off on that site or to retain it at its current levels. Just post something on your site's meta and link us to it.

## What now?

We want to increase the number of automated flags from 3 to 5 to reduce the time spam spends alive on the network. We'd like to hear your thoughts. We appreciate that quite a lot of the stuff we do at Charcoal is fairly invisible to the sites, so we want to be as open as possible. If you'd like data or specific reports, let us know and we'll try to add them in - we already have a lot of reporting around autoflagging, so it may already exist. If there's other stuff we can do to explain or to help you make an informed decision about whether you want this, drop an answer or a comment on this post. Charcoal members will be hanging around this post to respond to your concerns, or you can also [visit us in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540).

Comment: Duh! still [no free hand circles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291301/can-a-machine-be-taught-to-flag-spam-automatically#comment945768_291301)? Where do I look?

Comment: [Just for you](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7qJj.png), @BhargavRao.

Comment: What about sites that only require three flags to nuke a post? Will that be increased to two autoflags?

Comment: @Ano They're excluded from the experiment above. If we go to 5, I would expect those two sites to go to 2 flags (one manual to nuke, just like the 5 on a 6-flag site).

Comment: @Undo ArtOfCode says they get just one autoflag, but you say they get none...who's correct?

Comment: @Ano 'Excluded from the experiment' means 'we kept the status quo' - the status quo for the 3-flag sites is currently a single flag.

Comment: @Undo This was not clear from the original post. Also, I'd recommend editing in what is the plan for those 3-flag sites.

Comment: There are only two "three flag sites" and there will probably be zero in the near future. Let's not get sidetracked.

Comment: @Shog9 Did those two sites get their thresholds changed before Smokey started to take off? Is it because of Smokey that there are plans to get them changed back to six flags?

Comment: @Ano There was a big wave on Workplace and ELU a while back; three flags was meant to be a stopgap and just... never got changed. It's not really worth discussing in depth here; those sites are a small portion of the network in any statistic you look at.

Comment: Sounds like this system should be put on the front end, checking posts before they are even published, instead of having to wait for individual users to raise flags (even automatically).

Comment: We'd like to, @JoshCaswell, but that requires integration with SE and SE dev time, which is short right now.

Comment: One thing that I'd prefer to change is users who opt in choose what sites they can auto flag on. I'm not active on SU and I wouldn't really feel comfortable flagging over there even if it is for the benefit of the site.  However, I am active on SFF and would be comfortable letting my account auto flag. Would this be something you'd consider adding/changing?

Comment: @TheLethalCoder You can already select which sites you want to flag on.

Comment: Also as others have said I like the idea of setting this up per site with a discussion on that site beforehand. On SO it's very beneficial and probably worthwhile having more auto flags. Whereas, on SFF we already clean up quite quickly. It'd be nice to change settings (On/Off, No of auto flags) per site depending on that sites community consensus.

Comment: @Andy Ahh okay, it was this line that got me thinking about that `who may or may not be active on the site.` And I'm not really sure I like someone not familiar with a site auto flagging content because that makes them harder to get in contact with in case of any mistakes. Even though they can likely be contacted through other means.

Comment: FWIW I support this proposal and would like to see it go forward, I'd just like more community input on a per site basis before applying it network wide.

Comment: Is it mostly *answers* that you end up flagging, or mostly *questions*?

Comment: @TheLethalCoder If you don't have an account on a site, you can't autoflag there... so unless you've joined all of the sites, you're not going to have to limit it too much. :)

Comment: @Catija Aye but I have a few accounts but I'm only active on SFF. My SO and PPCG accounts are both >5k rep but I'm not active on any of them. Having the account doesn't mean you're active on it. I do see your point though.

Comment: @ChrisW questions: [28036](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/search?post_type=question&autoflagged=Yes) vs. [2470](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/search?post_type=answer&autoflagged=Yes) answers.

Comment: As an alternate solution to this problem, could StackExchange implement a system that hides posts with multiple spam flags from the site until they are dealt with in a review queue (one way or the other)? That would accomplish "You will see a reduction in the time spam spends on the site before being deleted." and "Fewer humans will have to involuntarily see each spam post." without reducing human oversight on the flags.

Comment: @Ajedi32 SE Dev time is limited, unfortunately. We've had discussions in past about how we can better be integrated. There are also other feature requests for new/improved moderator tooling that would certainly help with some of the other problems mentioned in this post. At the moment, though, asking for large system changes from SE seems to be a non-starter.

Comment: Your website at https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com is throwing errors whenever I go to half the pages on it. Doesn't exactly instill confidence.

Comment: @DuncanXSimpson Mind throwing me a stack trace in a gist or image?

Comment: @Undo Absolutely! https://pastebin.com/EbiJM7WQ Also, I can't reproduce any of the others now that I'm authenticated, so it makes sense that those bugs were missed

Comment: @DuncanXSimpson Probably not a bug per se; we were out of disk space for a moment there

Comment: Thanks @DuncanXSimpson; it's a known issue that pops up occasionally. Should be fixed now.

Comment: @Undo Alright, not a problem. I've signed up for it, by the way

Comment: Could you edit the post - it’s not clear if the time to deletion is measured from the moment the post is live until the post is deleted or the timing is from the first time the system or a person contemplates / takes action on the post.

Comment: Do you have any statistics on how many page views happen during that reduction from 50 to 10 second reduction in time?  I don't care about 40 seconds difference unless you can prove that a significant number of people see the spam during that time.

Comment: @CodyP View counts are cached for "a bit" - I don't know the exact time period - so accurate numbers aren't possible, at least not via the API.

Comment: There should be Six Flags Over Georgia.

Comment: @CodyP Ultimately, each spam post takes six flags to delete (ignoring moderators for a moment). Dropping the number of human eyes that have to look at this stuff from 3 to 1 is a huge benefit IMO. Some of it is nasty, nasty stuff designed to haunt the mind - at a minimum, we're cutting the number of people who have to view it to destroy it by that much.

Comment: Guide for the perplexed: the OP uses the word "nuke" here [against the conventional sense](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307585/307606?noredirect=1#comment1000632_307606), and in fact means something more like "quarantine". I.e. not *irrevocable deletion*, merely *revocable suppression from the default Q&A listings and search results until further manual review*. (This misuse of the word is unfortunate and seems to have already clouded the discussion in several cases. I would be grateful if the OP could edit the post for comprehensibility.)

Comment: @Ajedi32, I think that what you are asking for is pretty much what the OP is proposing. Unfortunately, the OP's misuse of the term "nuke" has [clouded that fact](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307585#comment1000643_307585).

Comment: @sampablokuper How we've used the word "nuke" here is in line with how the rest of SE uses it. I appreciate it's possible to not have come across that usage before, but that doesn't make it invalid - it simply has a slightly different meaning on SE than you're used to.

Comment: @ArtOfCode, *"we've used the word "nuke" here ... in line with how the rest of SE uses it"*. That is clearly false, or else a longstanding (~9-yr) SE user like me would have understood your usage. Evidently, there is an in-group of SE users that has developed its own jargon, perhaps unconsciously, that is at odds with conventional usage. If I were among that in-group, and hoping to communicate effectively with other SE users, I would be grateful to have been alerted to the likely incomprehensibility of that jargon outside of the in-group. I hope my comments here will be viewed in that spirit.

Comment: Can u share the 1 post that was incorrectly marked as spam? Curious.

Comment: @Andrew Not quite what you're thinking - there's one post that, had we been running autoflagging at the time, would have been flagged under the settings we're proposing for 5 flags. That's [this post](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/post/24413) (the question marks are standing in for Korean characters that weren't stored correctly as UTF8).

Comment: Yet another example of why SO should just open-source everything and leave its users to build a better experience than its dev team of (apparently) 1 person.

Comment: @ArtOfCode, re: "nuke", also see Shog9's comment [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307585/a-machine-can-flag-spam-automatically-can-it-do-better/307606?noredirect=1#comment1000705_307606). And to address a statement you made: I did not say the OP's usage was "invalid". I said it was liable to be misunderstood. (There's a difference.) I also explained *why* it was likely to be misunderstood. Please accept that feedback in the constructive spirit in which I gave it, and let's avoid [outgroup derogation](https://v.gd/MyjGJZ). Thanks :)

Comment: @IanKemp Thats a bit of an unfair comparison, if you mean charcoal, that's a arge group effort

Comment: That's not the way the system, current checks and balances, or the project work. We are already running our spam prevention and detection. Everything we've seen and removed it auditable.

Comment: @Peterverleg Everything we do at charcoal is 100% public record. The project itself is open source and open to all members of stack exchange. Such a thing would get noticed incredibly quickly. So no, we don't have that power.

Comment: I just want to say, as much as I use Stack Overflow, I _never_ see any spam on it, and that's a real testament to how well the system already works. Good job.

Comment: Are there multiple spam-flagging systems out there? As in, if Charcoal auto-voted 5 times could another autoflagging system provide the 6th flag?

Comment: @Undo In response to your response about how the point is "dropping the number of human eyes that have to look at this stuff from 3 to 1 is a huge benefit IMO".  However according to Andy "The major thing we're looking for out of this is a reduction in time to deletion."  I understand reducing moderator views from 3 to 1 is a good point, but either we need to critically evaluate the value of 40-seconds-less median TTD, or Andy should change his question to deemphasize TTD.

Comment: @CodyP There's two things here: Dropping the number of human eyes is a great benefit. Andy is also correct: "we're hoping to see a moderate reduction in the average times, and a significant reduction in the top outliers.". Take a look at [that graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kph8d.png) - getting rid of the 120+ second outliers is another motivator. There are multiple good outcomes from this, all equally valid (and hard to fit all of them in one meta post short enough for anyone to read).

Comment: @simonalexander2005 None that I'm aware of, but it's a valid point. We'd likely see any new system like that come up (or CMs would) and work with them on how to avoid double-flagging a post with similar heuristics.

Comment: How are posts being evaluated spam/not spam for calculating accuracy? And how is 99.99% meaningful? .01% is less than the margin of error. How correlated are human false positives? What impact does reputation have on posts being marked as spam?

Comment: @Acccumulation - `How are posts being evaluated spam/not spam for calculating accuracy?` That's based on human feedback to the system, and the system calculates the accuracy of each "reason" that caught the post based on the feedback that posts caught by that reason get. So if "URL in title" gets more posts marked as true positives than "bad keyword in body", it will have a higher weight and will be considered more accurate than the other reason.

Comment: @Accumulation As you say, 1 in 30,000 (or even less) is a tiny percentage, so data on human false positives on posts in this level of accuracy just doesn't exist.

Comment: Reputation is already taken into account on the 100.00% number; higher reputation (anything above 1) is a strong indicator of a post not being spam and excludes it from many checks. All told, [only 25 posts were autoflagged from users with >= 2 rep](https://m.erwaysoftware.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&title=&body=&username=&why=&site=&post_type=&feedback=&autoflagged=Yes&reason=&user_rep_direction=%3E%3D&user_reputation=2&commit=Search), only one being eligible for five flags under this change.

Comment: @Undo We don't necessarily need that level of precision for human false positives. If the human false positive rate is, e.g. 2.03%, it isn't a big deal if that gets rounded off to 2%.  And we could get *that* level of precision with much less data.

Comment: @Ray Oh, I mean the data *really* doesn't exist for posts at this accuracy. There was one false positive and it was handled correctly - but it wouldn't be right to say we had 100% accuracy. You'd have to extrapolate from some other accuracy level.

Comment: @Undo I don't have access to the site analytics, so I'm working in the dark here, but what about the figure in Bhargav Rao's answer?  It looks like there exist records somewhere of how many spam votes individual answers got even if they weren't marked as spam in the end.  That would let us compute the false positive rate *per vote* rather than per decision.  For the bot, those are the same since it either casts all of its votes or none of them.  But for humans, the votes are (approximately) independent.

Comment: I would like to see Charcoal setting a boolean on StackExchange's end, such that multiple denied flags in a short time period don't result in a ban for the user. I like the idea, and it has great accuracy, but it's an awfully large risk to take.

Comment: @Ray I went through all the false positives autoflagging has had on Stack Overflow the other day (18). I looked at whether a manual flag had been cast on the post after the autoflags. 2 out of 18 posts had manual flags cast on them - both were far below the threshold we would set for five flags. So I can give you 11% as a *very* rough starting number. Also, I disagree with the idea that individual flaggers are independent - it would stand to reason that what fools one flagger has a high chance of fooling another. That plays out every day in Stack Overflow's flag queue.

Comment: @jhpratt Not sure I quite see what you're getting at. Are you suggesting that we mark which accounts are used for autoflagging somehow so that SE systems won't automatically flag-ban them if autoflags get declined a lot? If so, that's not necessary - autoflags are accurate enough that they're _not_ going to get declined in anywhere near the volume required for a flag ban.

Comment: @ArtOfCode That's exactly what I'm saying. Don't get me wrong, I don't think it'll happen to anyone, but it is theoretically a possibility.

Comment: What does "400 hours per day" mean?

Comment: @henning: Consider the time a spam post is "live" on a site. That 400 hours is the total "live" time of all spam posted on a single day. For example: 100 posts in 1 day, with an average time to deletion of 5 minutes would mean 500 _minutes_ in a day. That 400 hours is a order of magnitude more.

Comment: "and a 10x drop in the outliers" -- you have a very skew distribution and only a few dozen points in each group; the number of outliers will itself be a fairly skewed random variable. I don't know that the evidence that there will really be a reduction in the proportion of outliers (by the boxplot rule) is very solid; if you computed some kind of confidence interval for that multiplicative reduction (around your estimate of 10x) I expect it would be pretty wide.

Comment: @Glen_b I think you may be looking at the wrong boxplot for that one. The all-blue boxplot is the results of last week's experiment. Look instead at the top boxplot, which is of TTD on the top few sites. There's much more data in that one about the TTD for outliers.

Comment: Seems like this is more of a question for SO users on Kaggle than SO users on SO. But the answer is, yes, of course.

What I mean by this is that the spam detection should be made (much) more effective by collaborative and competitive community programming of the detection algorithm as we often do on Kaggle.

Comment: Depends on what the criteria is for a 99% confident flag. Is that public knowledge? (It prob shouldn't be ;) If it's people's emails, phone numbers, and general animosity, then bump it up to six and be done with it. Anything else requires human intervention, and SE requires *far* more than one human to intervene by design.

Comment: @Mazura All of our tests can be found [here](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/SmokeDetector/blob/master/findspam.py). We add up the accuracy percentages, then flag based on the total.

Comment: @Undo You forgot to update the raw number data, lololol.

Comment: I thought it was a neat idea and signed up. The system flags an average of 200+ posts a day, using 300+ supposed active users. In eight days, my account did not cast one vote. I would steer clear of this system, which requires full account permission in order to (not) vote. Very shady.

Comment: @oMiKeY The system is weighted to use certain accounts more than others - accounts belonging to Charcoal's core contributors are weighted more highly. IOW, 2/3 of flags are distributed between approximately 30 users, and the remaining 1/3 are distributed between the remaining ~270 users. We're also only flagging around 70 posts per day, not 200. So, I'd expect to see 70 flags/day (1/3 of 210 total flags/day) between 270 users. Randomly distributed, that's a flag every 4 days, _if_ you're set up as permissively as possible. And that's still only approximate math, likely overestimated.

Comment: @oMiKeY We have a lot of new users since this post was submitted. Slightly less than a half of all the automatic flags are distributed among "new users", so it's quite possible that a single user don't get a flag distributed to their account in a few days.

Comment: My numbers in that last comment are outdated, actually - we're currently distributing the last third between around 500 users, not 270. That would easily explain the 8 days figure.

Comment: fair enough. i'm a bit of a nervous nancy, technologically speaking.

Answer (score 125):

I see a very big difference between moving to 4 or to 5 automatic flags. I wouldn't have any issue with 4 flags, but 5 flags means that only a single user is required to nuke the post. This would probably still be safe if that single user organically stumbles upon the spam post, in this case the odds of a user falsely flagging a false positive are very low. But that isn't the case I'd be worried about. As far as I understand, you keep links to auto-flagged posts in various places, which is pretty much necessary for this system to be administered. A single overzealous user monitoring flagged posts and adding their own would be rather dangerous, if they are careless.

The odds of actually getting a non-spam post nuked are incredibly low if you assume that all flags are independent. But this assumption isn't necessarily true if you have a list of possible spam posts that users use to find posts to flag.

I also see seriously diminishing returns here. Making sure that most spam is removed in a few minutes is a worthy goal. I'm not convinced pushing it below a minute is worth additional risk.

One other concern of mine would be how Charcoal handles the far more murky area of self-promotion. My understanding is that there aren't any automatic flags that target posts that are likely to be self-promotion, but not blatant spam. But this is an area that confuses real users as well, so it would be particularly dangerous in combination with the 5 flag option.

In general, I like the project and do support automatically flagging posts on all sites. My major concern is that it isn't transparent at all unless you know it exists. You're using real user account to flag, a moderator that doesn't follow the main meta might never know there are any automatic spam flags, as they only ever see real users. This is not a new concern, but I think transparency is even more important if you increase the automatic flagging in this way.

Comment: The [graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Slp5.png) in the post illustrates the accuracy of the automatic part of 5 flags. As for the human element on that last flag, you're right that it's not necessarily independent. However, while some people are more zealous than others in flagging, multiple (significant, not just 2) people look at each post, and any disagreement will start raising alerts. That means it would take probably 4 or 5 people agreeing the post was spam for a false last flag to go unnoticed, and even then I might still pick it up when I read the day's transcripts.

Comment: Meanwhile, the transparency issue is something we're always looking to improve where possible. We'd like to hear it if you've got suggestions on that front (that goes for anyone, not just @Mad).

Comment: @ArtOfCode this puts the review of potentially bad spam flags entirely on the Charcoal team, the individual site communites and mods can't review this case (unless they know about Charcoal and monitor the site actively). I'm slightly uncomfortable with that.

Comment: I can understand not being entirely comfortable with it. Let us know if we can alleviate that, of course. FWIW, I don't believe I've ever seen a bad spam flag that's gone unnoticed by the Charcoal team. That's anecdotal, of course, not hard evidence.

Comment: Oh - and on the self-promotion thing: you're right, autoflags stay away from that. It's too much of a varied issue for us to apply a network-wide filter to.

Comment: The best way to improve transparency would be to have a dedicated account (or pseudo-account or five) to do the flagging, but that would require dev team assistance (and the discussion of its merits should go to Petter's answer)

Comment: What would be the best way for us to resolve your concerns? We can do nearly any reporting you need, just let us know what that might look like.

Comment: @Undo I don't see any solution except dedicated bot accounts with a link to an explanation in their profile. Everything else would rely on moderators knowing about Charcoal in the first place, and knowing where exactly to look. Dedicated accounts would allow moderators to review the flags with the existing tools, and it would make it clear to them that they are automated.

Comment: Let's explore that a bit @MadScientist. I'm not promising this, but it's an option: What if each post got *one* flag from the SmokeDetector account (with relevant profile links), and the rest done the same way as now? I think that'd solve your concern without burdening us with creating 5-10 accounts and getting rep.

Comment: @Undo by that I assume you mean a custom flag?

Comment: I was thinking a spam flag, but from an obvious bot account @ArtOfCode. Custom flags are messy in other ways.

Comment: @Undo ideally said bot account would be generated by the grace of CMs, complete with unlimited flags and the ability to flag the same post multiple times.

Comment: Highly unlikely to happen @JohnDvorak - that'd be dev time, which isn't justifiable for this small a benefit.

Comment: @Undo there's still be a bit of potential confusion for moderators that don't know how it works, but it would solve almost all of my transparency concerns.

Comment: We'll look at that, then. I'll let you know if we come up with a different way to do it.

Comment: @ArtOfCode About the self-promotion. In Bioinformatics we recently had problems when a new user posted an answer with his own software and a user came from the chat with some aggressive wording . See [this](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73895/discussion-on-answer-by-bernatgel-how-to-make-chromosome-color-maps-for-bed-rang) chat. It has triggered a discussion on the meta site to change the restrictions. But I would advocate to let the beta site on their own.

Comment: @Llopis, We've discussed that situation with a local moderator. The solution we've agreed on is to refrain from posting comments indicating how self promotion can be perceived.

Comment: What is we asked autoflagging users to put something in their bio about it? Not ideal but might alleviate a bit in lieu of bot accounts.

Comment: I think the key here is that, 5 flags is only for posts that have a higher probability of being spam. So we should ask more questions. What percentage of total flagged posts is this? And what are the current accuracy stats on this "level' of posts?

Comment: @alexr101 Five flags is far more risk than three, as a bunch of people here note. We take that into account when choosing accuracy levels. Our current consideration would have been 100.00% accurate over the 29,702 posts that would have matched this condition. See [the accuracy graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Slp5.png). Fun fact - that one red dot in that graph isn't there any more. The system found more data in the last few days, learned from it, and that post's weight dropped below the threshold. I expect total percentage of flagged posts getting 5 flags, going forward, to be around 63%.

Comment: @Undo Yeah, I get the risk factor, but if the accurracy for these higher risk posts is 100% (so far) then the chances are extremely low that a legit post will get deleted. Since the rest of the posts will still get only 3 flags, right? That's just my 2 cents. I don't see that much risk given the reward :)

Comment: That's exactly how I see it, @alexr101. Yes, the rest of the posts would keep the current status quo.

Answer (score 76):

The biggest advantage I see in how the Smoke Detector project has operated thus far is its *transparency*: one of the most frustrating aspects of using these sites is how difficult it can be to determine precisely *what happened* in a given scenario (much less *why* it happened) - even for moderators, there's so much data that's either unavailable or more often available but *not clearly connected* that making sense of the sequence of events that underpin a complaint can be a real chore. For ordinary users, deciphering something odd they encounter can require knowledge of [hidden tools](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126447/add-a-link-to-the-timeline-of-a-post) and a 4-year degree in Meta Minutiae.

But Smoke Detector? It's all right there, out in the open and heavily crosslinked. What got reported, why / who reported it, what the post said and who wrote it, when it was created, when it was deleted, who flagged it... A massive record of spam in all its gory detail, laid out for review by anyone with an interest in doing so.

### Entrypoints

With that in mind, it might seem ironic that most of the concerns expressed here relate in some way to accountability. But it's not: for all the data (and powerful searching / filtering exposed in the web interface), Smoke Detector suffers from one of the same problems that afflicts so many otherwise-powerful systems on Stack Exchange - *discoverability!*

- There's no obvious way for me to see (as a user or moderator browsing my site) what - if anything - has been identified, flagged or deleted by the Smoke Detector project.
- If I *do* come across a spam-deleted post, there's no obvious indicator that Smoke Detector had any involvement in this. The most likely route for me to discover this would be to observe a comment from someone not normally active on my site, but this rare occurrence lends itself to observing only activity on borderline posts; my perception of both the scope and worth of the project is inevitably skewed.

Fortunately, I think these concerns can be addressed fairly easily. My initial recommendation would be to generate a monthly report for every site on which Smoke Detector has identified posts, summarizing statistics for the post(s) identified and linking to [a search](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/search?site=72) that provides the full list of posts for perusal by those who might be interested. Such a report could be posted on each meta site on a regular basis, thus providing both transparency *and awareness* of the project without intruding on the day-to-day operations of the site itself.

For moderators researching specific complaints, a userscript to look up SD data on any spam-deleted post should suffice to allay concerns about false-positives going unnoticed. This would potentially require a bit of extra support from the Smoke Detector project, but I don't think it would need much work.

Thoughts?

Comment: Easy to do a userscript; meta posts could be automated from a template and posted from the bot itself every 3-6 months. I like it, thanks for weighing in.

Comment: We have the brand new site dashboard on Metasmoke that does exactly this, but some mods are (understandably) wary of relying on a third party tool.

Comment: I'm not overly concerned about the 3rd-party aspect, @quartata - rather, there's nothing on any Stack Exchange site that would clue you into its existence if you didn't go out of your way to look for it. It's like the 10K tools on SO, except there isn't even a faint grey link in /review - awesome stuff, but nobody knows it exists.

Comment: Monthly report * 173 sites = quite a bit of undertaking, unless those posts are being generated by a bot (through an account that accepts pings, ideally)

Comment: @quartata The problem (to me at least) is less the third party nature and more the fact that *I* have to *go check*, rather than just *being told*. If that being told isn't a genuine SE review queue but whatever private message, e-mail, or just chat bot, that's still better than having me *remember* checking out the dashboard.

Comment: An alternate (but to my mind much more obnoxious) route here would be to raise an "other" flag on each autoflagged post with a SD link to the report, @Undo. I hate that idea because it'd be a massive pile of flags requiring no action in the vast, vast majority of cases, but for very quiet sites it might make more sense than a userscript.

Comment: @Shog9 why not just give mods access to posts recently six-flagged?

Comment: Running as fast as allowed by SE's rate-limiter, it would take less than 5 days to run for all sites, @John. That doesn't seem terribly onerous.

Comment: Automating report meta posts every _n_ months is pretty easy once you get to the technical details of it; totally happy to do that. Probably worth letting sites say they don't want the posts, though.

Comment: @ArtOfCode now, responding to pings will be fun

Comment: Yanno? I'd actually be happier with at least one custom flag, especially if its sticky. And it feels like something worth testing

Comment: Perhaps there'd be a way to set up an annual meta post and each month a new answer is added? Some of the sites I use barely have 12 posts per year... just naturally.

Comment: @JohnDvorak metasmoke can alert CHQ when it makes a post; we can watch it for pings. Not out of the question at all.

Comment: I wasn't worried about the technical aspect of that, but rather about the peak volume we'd be dealing with.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I think that would be something that might be better left up to the mods of the site... I don't know that the CMs will want to wade through the mass of them that get posted here... or that we need to overburden the SO mods with the huge volume they get.

Comment: My opinion may be a bit skewed by Stack Overflow, @JourneymanGeek, but these seem like flags that'd *really pile up fast* and end up just getting ignored on sites with literally anything else to do.

Comment: "literally nothing else to do" can't possibly happen. Even if mods get really bored, they could review edit suggestions or even answer some questions.

Comment: @Shog9 The SO mod flag queue is pretty bad already :P

Comment: Its probably skewed by SO ;p.

Comment: Strictly-speaking, mods already have *access* to that @John, it's just not a clean or convenient filter. Which leaves us with essentially the same problem described above: nobody knows it exists, those that do don't have access, those that do don't think to look for it, and those that remember don't want to slog through it.

Comment: There are some *really* quiet sites moderation-wise, @John. These flags might be all that keep some mod-teams from going stir crazy. *The Diamond Madness*, they call it - one day you stumble on a lonely forgotten cabin in the woods, perhaps to take shelter from the driving snow, and upon opening the door you see the desiccated corpse in the blue hat... bony fingers still clutching that last flag.

Comment: If users could [provide freeform text entry alongside any type of flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301835/when-flagging-a-post-or-comment-provide-a-freeform-text-entry-field-for-all-rea), Smokey could submit autoflags with a freeform entry of "Smoke Detector autoflag (report link)", and submit non-automated flags made via manual review via "Smoke Detector flag, cast by a human during review (report link)". Not that I want to use this to plug a thing I suggested, but... this seems like an ideal & relevant time to mention that thing.

Comment: There's that. One reason I *didn't* stand for SR.SE elected mod was... I didn't feel I was handling enough flags, cause I apparently didn't have that many in my timezone. You need mods to handle flags, but as a mod, I gotta have *something* to do.

Comment: @Shog9 Do 'other' flags stick around after a 6-flag spam nuke? That's a big reason I've opposed it on SO, but if they stick around it might be okay for small sites.

Comment: Might be possible to do a combo approach - 'other' flags on the smallest sites spam-wise, meta posts on the ones large enough to have meaningful data.

Comment: @Undo they stick around.

Comment: @Undo tweaking this will be fun :P

Comment: @Undo SD could always flag (1 of the flags) and then x site basis you decide if spam flag or other depending on moderator team decision on relative site. I know lot of config :(, but often it's the only way to keep all happy.

Answer (score 69):

The thing that concerns me about 5 auto-flags is that sometimes users are wrong and now it only takes one user to spam-delete a post.  A statistic that would help me better evaluate this is: on each site, how many *organic* spam flags are dismissed or disputed?  If even *site users* sometimes get it wrong -- and they do, particularly on questions where product links in answers are expected -- then allowing a *single user*, native or (especially) visiting from Charcoal, to cast binding spam flags gives me pause.  But I have anecdotes, not data; can we get data?  (It would have to come from SE, I know.)

I'm glad to see your team working on tools to help moderators monitor what's going on.  I'm going to need push notifications, not just pull (the dashboard), which I understand is possible.

Comment: One point that makes this less of a problem is that the cases where single users even get the opportunity to make that mistake are 0,25% of all autoflagged posts, which are a medium subset of all spam posts on that site, which are a _really_ small subset of all posts on that site

Comment: Given that the users from SD see the reports, it is pretty likely that the sixth flag will come from a Charcoal visitor as well. I wonder though if that's much different with the three human flags used right now.

Comment: Please note that these automated flags are _only_ cast on posts of which the system is (at least) 99.75% sure it's spam. This means that only the really obviously blatant spam even has a _chance_ of having 1 "real" user cast a binding vote. (Just to prevent confusion)

Comment: @Cerbrus Five flags would probably be cast on posts we're 100.00% sure on. One false positive in 30k, historically.

Comment: Monica, what push notifications would you want?

Comment: I'm trying to get data on how accurate Charcoal people are. As a baseline, overall human flaggers are accurate on spam 95.4% of the time.

Comment: Rough data says Charcoal folks are 99.27% accurate.

Comment: @JAD that's a good point; it'd be interesting to know to what extent spam is *already* being flagged entirely by people who are not otherwise users on the site.  (Not sure how to measure that -- users whose only participation is flagging vs users with other activity, maybe?)

Comment: @Undo probably a feed into a chat room of posts that were deleted with Smokey multi-flags.  Or that Smokey multi-flagged, I guess, since that's going to be nearly identical and might be easier to generate.  I'm open to other implementations; I know you can feed notices to chat rooms now and that seems like it'd work for this purpose.  Also, thanks to you and Cerbrus for clarifying the higher bar for this to happen at all; I missed that.

Comment: @ArtOfCode is that data available per-site?  Since I don't know how my sites compare to others, an aggregate number doesn't necessarily tell me what's happening on *my* sites.

Comment: It's not at the moment, no. The 95.4% is a number we got from jmac last year; the 99.27% is a strawpoll of Charcoal who were present when I asked.

Comment: That can be done. Could even build an RSS feed of flagged posts you could plumb into your email/chatroom/IRC/whatever - would that work? It'd be a few minutes slower than straight Smokey posts, but far more flexible.

Comment: @MonicaCellio I don't think there is a way to find out without a CM's help :/

Comment: @Undo assuming the RSS "payload" (what gets shown in chat) has the title and link to the post in question, that'd be fine.  I don't care if there's a delay; this is for auditing, not immediate action.

Comment: @MonicaCellio For the purposes of auditing, there's also MetaSmoke, which stores a _lot_ of data about Smokey's actions, including what posts have been reported -- complete with their content (displayed as HTML, to make things like hidden [l](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rickrolling)inks easier to spot. That info is available per-post, and the MetaSmoke page for each autoflagged post should also probably get put in that chatroom, so _anyone_ can audit, not just people with enough rep on each specific site.

Comment: @Nic that sounds like good info to add to chat. Demonstrably, off-site monitoring is "out of sight, out of mind" for me, which is why I need push notifications on some form. Maybe someday I'll have the metasmoke habit, but I don't now and I want to moderate my site from my site.

Comment: If you feel strongly about it there's a notification system where you can elect to be pinged on all SD reports for a given site

Comment: That's... sub-optimal for moderation, @Magisch. We need something like our site dashboard, but pushable rather than "there it is go get it".

Comment: @ArtOfCode or reports posted to site metas, or feeds into a chat room (*not* individual pings like Magisch seems to be suggesting), or something similar we haven't thought of.  Shog nailed it when he talked about *discoverability*; community members need to see it in their normal travels through their sites.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Feeding reports from a specific site into a specific chatroom is already possible, all the site needs to do is ask for it. In fact, setting this up takes less then 10 minutes iirc. Examples would be SO reports going to socvr or IPS reports going to the awkward silence.

Comment: @Magisch Monica's asking for a different system. Getting all reports for a site is not what's needed for this purpose, whether that's a Smokey room or notifications.

Comment: @MonicaCellio I've [made a pull request](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/metasmoke/pull/343) to add a "feed" that you can add to a chat room that will show all autoflagged posts (different feed for each site). Would that be enough to alleviate your concerns about push notification?

Comment: @thesecretmaster thanks.  Does the message contain a direct link to the post (like other Smokey messages)?  I assume so; just checking.  Yes, that alleviates the concern.

Comment: @ArtOfCode Your comparison to human flaggers is completely wrong. If a single human flagger is right r=95.4% of the time, then if you're casting three SD flags the benchmark you need to match is 1-(1-r)^3=99.99% accuracy. If you're casting *five* flags then your error rate needs to be of the order of one in five million. Human flaggers are independent, but you're proposing to do away with that redundancy, so your system needs to be that much better the more redundancy you want to cut.

Comment: @E.P. Thing is, human flaggers _aren't_ entirely independent. It would be very nice statistically if they were, but that's not the case. Humans are more likely to spam flag a post if it's already been spam flagged or negatively received; particular with the intervention of Charcoal folks, that means that human flags are interdependent and not statistically distinct.

Comment: @E.P. As to the error rate - honestly, we don't know. At the settings we're considering for five flags, there are _no_ false positives at present out of 30k posts matched. So, at present, it's 100% accurate, but we don't know when a false positive might turn up. It could be one in five million; it could be less. It could be more.

Comment: @ArtOfCode "Humans are more likely to spam flag a post if it's already been spam flagged" - I find that claim to be extremely dubious. How exactly do they find out about other users' (private) flags? For sure, there's a correlation (spam flags likely correlate with leaving a  downvote, and a negative score likely influences spam flags) but it's still independent assessments vs one single go. There's plenty of data to do a full-fledged analysis of the error rates of *n* human flaggers, but the fact that that's hard doesn't make the single-flagger rate any more meaningful.

Comment: @E.P. I don't have hard data on it - you'd need to convince a CM to get that - but the premise for human flaggers being not-independent is simple: If a given flagger (or two) makes a mistake on a post, it stands to reason that there's *something* about that post that tends to trip up humans. That plays out often in Stack Overflow's flag queue: multiple bad spam flags, from users with no apparent connection to each other.

Comment: FWIW, I'm happy to provide data on the accuracy of spam flaggers if requested... But please make it a separate question so I don't have to post that in a comment. Tease: it's probably a lot worse than you think it is.

Comment: @Undo That has minimal bearing on the argument. There is a sliding scale between "completely statistically independent" and "identical", but unless you're at that "identical" endpoint, the single-human error rate is a misleading metric to even quote. The question of what is a comparable error rate between independent humans seeing the posts and (not?) flagging them versus SD casting *n* automatic flags is a complicated one but it would be good to see you guys tackle it instead of pretending that the single-user rate is a passable substitute.

Comment: (Not to be dismissive, by the way - I think SmokeDetector is a pretty good thing to have around, but it *is* you guys that want to ratchet up the system to a pretty fragile place where a single human mis-flag has strong implications on other users' content, so the onus is on you to do that analysis, I should think.)

Comment: @Shog9 Magisch posted [a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307717/303707) about this.

Comment: @E.P. [Here's some hard numbers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/307750/215468) on human accuracy with spam flags.

Answer (score 42):

Art mentioned this [in a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307585/a-machine-can-flag-spam-automatically-can-it-do-better/307615#comment1000466_307589):

> However, while some people are more zealous than others in flagging

I dunno whether bad luck, or good that it occurred, this happened yesterday:

[image]

The red color marked user is a well known overzealous flagger. I've seen many of their spam flags being retracted just a few seconds after flagging and then using a NAA flag. The blue marked user is a highly respected member of Charcoal (or atleast, I respect them a lot), and who is quite good at taking decisions.

In this case, the overzealous user flagged the post almost immediately. A few seconds later, the trusted user naa- reviewed the smokey post. After that the first user retracted the flag immediately and added a naa flag.

This wouldn't be a problem usually, but it would make a difference if that user is given the task of being the 6th flagger on a post with 5 auto flags.

Some suggestions to prevent this:

- Check if a user has lots of invalidated feedback and flag it from their account, so that you can be sure that they are not the 6th flagger.
- Check if a user has lots of invalidated feedback and stop/scold/educate the user to be more careful.
- Use just 4 instead of 5, but this has the disadvantage (from the data) that it doesn't help much. So I'm not much attached to the "use 4 instead of 5" statement.

You people are quite brilliant at this, and can figure out a better way. My only request is to somehow make sure that a overzealous users isn't the deciding factor, if you are flagging 5.

Good luck!

Comment: Hot-headed users could be filtered out empirically. Say, give a one-week cool-down if you mistakenly nuke a post with your one manual flag. If it recurs, make it a month. And by cool-down I mean flag ban ;)

Comment: @AndrasDeak Well certain moderators on smaller sites do send a mod message to users who wrongly flag. But I think we shouldn't be going to that level. Charcoal must ensure that it doesn't go to such an extreme level. And no, mods can't add flag bans. If that was the case, I would have done that.

Comment: Aw, too bad :( Back to the drawing board, I guess ;)

Comment: Are you saying the overzealous problem flagger actually is *a proper Charcoal user* (upto the point of having their account registered for auto-flagging)? Maybe *that* says something too and ought to be investigated, rather than thinking how best to "cripple" them.

Comment: @ChristianRau Yep, they're a registered user. I've marked a few of their autoflags as helpful.

Comment: If that is remotely a possibility to happen, that speaks pretty clearly for *not* giving individual Charcoal users *unilateral* spam-deletion powers.

Comment: Yep @ChristianRau, that's true. That's the point of this post. However, I'd not say "Charcoal users" collectively, but just the small bunch of them who are a bit trigger happy. Most of the Charcoal guys are quite proficient in handling spam (like I mentioned about the trusted user).

Comment: While this does demonstrate that some people are overzealous, it does also speak well of our review process - even though an incorrect flag was cast, it was caught almost immediately by other Charcoal members. That's a good illustration of why a post isn't going to get deleted and forgotten about; if this happens (which is rare), then we'll know about it and be able to alert the necessary people.

Comment: Yup @Art, it's because of the good people who review them properly that Charcoal is now famous. I'm just pointing out a very minor issue which I discovered accidentally. If we manage to fix these minor issues then we can certainly gain the trust of others who are a bit skeptical of the system. (I hope my post didn't come across as "STAP IT IMMEDIATELY", as that is not my intention)

Comment: Not at all, @BhargavRao, just wanted to highlight that element of it. There are definitely ways we can put a clampdown on things like this happening.

Answer (score 35):

Smoke detector is a fantastic project, it has inspired many of us to do other type of moderation bots.

However once [Brad Larson](https://stackexchange.com/users/10416/brad-larson?tab=accounts) stated in this [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333397/to-nuke-or-not-to-nuke-that-is-the-question#comment388863_333403) on a question that I made

> I'm not terribly excited about a chatroom gathering together to coordinate flags on content in order to automatically delete it

I realize that the main objective remove spam quickly is important but I think we that coordinate flags/actions in chatroom has a great responsibility to listen to moderators on specific site (they have been elected) and we need to assure the members who do not participate in chat/flagging are never targeted or gamified.

With that said, these are some ideas to leverage the great capability of SmokeDetector to find spam and keep community moderators involved.

- Get moderators involved on each site, listen and let'em decide how many auto-flags you can cast, as a side note I would be ok that moderator [directly cast flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291301/can-a-machine-be-taught-to-flag-spam-automatically/291311#291311) if they think that it's the best solution, they will be responsabile since community has put their trust in them.
- Instead of using other users "real" accounts, create SmokeDetector flag account eg. SD_FLAGGER1, this will both remove the idea of user participating to get "free" flags and badges (I know they get very few flags but just the idea taste bad for the community). More important, it will be clear to moderators who is flagging the post.

Keep up your excellent work!

Comment: How would you propose we get the moderators of each of the 172 sites involved more than a main meta post?

Comment: Of course. If individual sites have an issue with this, absolutely we'll work with them to find the best solution - whether that's off entirely, at current levels, or something else. The decision on that needs to be a community decision, though, not mod-only. The debate about bot accounts is ongoing.

Comment: Re: other accounts - that's essentially sockpuppeting, no? Who *owns* these accounts? That's essentially casting a flag with a sock and then manually flagging with your main account, which is pretty much a no-no.

Comment: @Mithrandir I can't understand your first comment? You will need to contact each moderator on each site (teacher lounge for example), regarding second comment is not 1 account (SD) casting 5 flags with other accounts?

Comment: @PetterFriberg the difference is that in one case you have five people vouching for Smokey, in the other you have Smokey vouching for himself. Another option would be to have the devs vouch for Smokey by  giving it a special privileged account, but that hasn't seemed necessary.

Comment: @JohnDvorak I prefer Smokey vouching for himself, since it's it casting flags, it's more clear/transparent for moderators and you avoid the free flag/free badge idea.  You do not need dev support, just setup flagging accounts.

Comment: @PetterFriberg: each account would need to get at least [15 rep](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to be able to flag. I'd rather see experienced users vouch for a tool, than a tool with the power of 5 users vouching for itself.

Comment: @Cerbrus not to mention that the latter is against the Rules As Written.

Comment: 15 rep is hardly a problem (7 edits), "experienced users"??, anyone can sign up!. "Rules As Written", @JohnDvorak for those rules it's same stuff always 1 bot using 5 other accounts. Are you sure no one has added a socket in this [list](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/flagging/ocs)?

Comment: Honestly if it's better for moderators (more clear), the only true objection would be "but my free flags!!!", I will not get them anymore.

Comment: and for SmokeDetector it's better to keep away that idea, as reputation the community is sensitive to "free"  flags, badge etc. For example Marshal is moderation badge, that counts in election, probably it is not so great to have a bot earning this for you or even contribute to earning it (if it was not you, yourself writing that bot)

Comment: @PetterFriberg: Take [my AskUbuntu account](https://askubuntu.com/users/643794/cerbrus). Yes, that's (recently) gotten the Marshal badge. I'm pretty sure I'd stand ___no chance___ in an election there, though. The fact that I got that badge there really doesn't mean anything. There are only [4 sites](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/graphs?timeframe=all#reports-by-site) with enough spam that one could get a badge like that in any reasonable time.

Comment: @Cerbrus it's the idea that you got a "free" badge that is bad (not that I personally care much) and since for moderators it would be easier to understand who and why the post was flag if they see "SD_FLAGGER_1" instead of random user, why not use SD_FLAGGER_1?, because you will not get the badge anymore :D?

Comment: *The concept is simply to avoid all these "free-flag/badge" discussions use flagging accounts.*

Comment: Because then there’s just MetaSmoke doing their thing. It’s not the community keeping an eye on it. It’s not the community setting the flagging conditions and threshold, @PetterFriberg. Users can set their own conditions and limits on what gets flagged using their accounts.

Comment: @Cerbrus, you have 215 users now casting random flags on random site, I doubt the overview would be different. We are already trusting Charcoal to keep an eye on things, more then we trust 1 of those 215 random users.

Comment: Do note that bot's casting flags by them self is not new atleast not on Stack Overflow [Can a machine be taught to flag Non-Answers and post comments on them automatically?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343065/can-a-machine-be-taught-to-flag-non-answers-and-post-comments-on-them-automatica)

Comment: I don't really understand why you'd ignore the aspect of those 215 users trusting SmokeDetector. That's an extra layer of trust above what MetaSmoke already gets from community managers / moderators. There aren't nearly as many NAA flags required as spam flags, a single account for spam just won't cut it. 5 _fake_ accounts to take care of the 5 auto-flags just seems more dubious... Ideally, we'd have a way of identifying a user's cast flags as cast from the API using MetaSmoke. But again, that'd require dev time to add a parameter to the API & flagging mod interface.

Comment: @Cerbrus for NAA only 1 flag is needed  ;), and for the 215 users lets remove the idea that many of them have signed in to get free flags (I see this a lot, people like badge's and flag like crazy). You don't need this mess, 4 more SD account's and things get crystal clear.

Comment: @PetterFriberg: On a busy day there can be [~275 autoflags cast](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/flagging). With 10 flags per account, MS would need __28 accounts__. ([10 flag cap, bottom of the page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts))... That's not exactly ideal.

Comment: @Cerbrus the limit is per site, after a while every account will have 100 flags on each site.

Comment: @PetterFriberg The bot accounts debate is one we had last time round. At the moment, it's not a course we're interested in following, for various reasons. I'll give you a ping if it comes up in future, though ;)

Comment: I really like the idea of having Smokey accounts to both remove the badge incentive (yes that's a thing for some people) and communicate clearly to mods where the flags are coming from.

Comment: Brad's comment is easily countered when you consider the fact that moderators have the ability to automatically delete content *unilaterally*, which is even more powerful than what this entails. The only difference is that moderators get elected (and many moderators have come from such organized chatrooms, so it's not like these are completely untrustworthy users compared to saints/white knights)

Comment: If the concern is really that strong re: badges and flag count / stats, then frankly we should probably talk about this behavior getting set to 100% accuracy threshold and rolled into the Community user and monitored by devs and CMs instead of users.

Comment: @TylerH We'd love to do that, but it's SE dev time. There have been a couple efforts to do that; they've all fizzled out. It's not worth integration for the benefit over what we have now (especially if we could reliably nuke spam <10s after creation)

Comment: I agree that rolling Smokey HQ into existing accounts creates transparency and understandability issues. Just last month we had a post by a user (actually me) who was suspicious about how on Security SE "There are about 23% of downvotes that come from 14 users who collectively have submitted 0.5% of posts in the past 5 years."  Many of those 14 users ended up being Charcoal HQ users.  I'd rather have "Smokey_Account" making questionable judgments than a low-rep user creating 100's of questionable and hard to track downvotes through Charcoal.

Comment: @CodyP i don't think SD votes on posts, just flags them.

Comment: @CodyP Could you throw me a link to that data? SmokeDetector never downvotes anything, ever.

Comment: [Found it myself](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2882/we-have-more-users-who-vote-lots-but-dont-ever-really-post-how-can-we-fix-it). Some users are downvoting spam manually. That's not affected in any way by autoflagging, be it more flags, less flags, or no flags. To quote Rory Alsop, [I see no problem here at all](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2882/we-have-more-users-who-vote-lots-but-dont-ever-really-post-how-can-we-fix-it#comment7350_2883)

Comment: @CodyP I actually can't see directly how it is related, the current auto-flags from user does not also downvote (apart from automatic community downvote since spam flag) so naturally an SD_FLAGGER would not cast also a downvote. The manual down voting from users seeing post (may it be by report) that they think merit down vote would not change.

Comment: @Undo Correct, the initial response to that question was that the downvotes were ok because most of them were probably on spam or other obviously bad posts.  So it's only tangentially related in that low-rep users were using Charcoal to find spam to downvote (and probably flag) and that caused some confusion on my part since I wasn't familiar with Charcoal and it's impossible to tell whether a user's huge number of downvotes are due to frequenting Charcoal or due to personal whim.

Answer (score 28):

I feel that the increased automated flags should be *opt-in* with the agreement of the moderation team, and community involved. At a broader level, I think the individual communities ought to have a say when *any* project may affect how it runs.

To me, the right workflow here would be to let the moderators be the point of contact, have the option of discussing and making a decision as representatives of the community and/or bringing it on meta. I *don't* feel comfortable with letting any organisation (Other than SE) making this decision for us.

And I think this is a big part of the issue here - that it takes things out of the hands of the individual community to a bigger extent than I'm comfortable with.

There's been  [a case of voting without knowing you did](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307471/awarded-deputy-badge-for-helpful-flags-i-havent-raised), I'm assured that its unlikely but its possible someone can opt in and forget. I'd *prefer* some more direct human input, personally.

While getting rid of individual cases of spam is a worthwhile endeavor, it also means that mods are less likely to notice and nuke the *accounts*. It's not just about time to deletion.

So, if it's a small community with a ton of spam, and they want it? This might work.

It's worth considering whether [we're optimising for paperclips](https://wiki.lesswrong.com/wiki/Paperclip_maximizer). 
As a moderator I have a ton of questions about this:

A. Does optimising for shorter lifetime for spam reduce the chances of them getting picked up on search engines?

B. What are the benefits for community outside the *outcome* of spam getting deleted faster?

C. How does this compare in time to deletion to *fewer* auto flags, or more precisely, what's the minimum number of flags at which auto flagging is useful?

D. As a downside, does this discourage people *outside* Smokey from flagging spam (since they don't get into the habit of it)?

Comment: Answers: (a) Yes. (b). That kinda is the main benefit, as well as fewer humans having to deal with spam. (c) There are stats in the post that answer that one - average TTD for 1 flag is ~190s, 3 flags ~50s, 5 flags ~10s. (d) No data, even anecdotal. I'd hope not, but it might happen on the smaller sites.

Comment: And while yes, it's possible to have spam flagged in your name without knowing about it, _that's explicitly what you're signing up for_ when you enable autoflagging on your account.

Comment: One benefit: I have a huge database of things you *really* don't want to look at for a variety of reasons. Nasty, nasty stuff that's designed to haunt you for a long time. Getting between 2 and 5 human eyes off of that is a huge benefit IMO.

Comment: Regarding that example where they voted without knowing...that's exactly what this post and the previous post I made were for. It informed the community about this project and allowed them to sign up to participate. It's not like we randomly selected a user to flag as. They had to authorize the use of their account. They clicked the button to do so. [They read the warning](https://i.imgur.com/Pct0aPh.png)

Comment: Regarding deleting spam accounts, would it be helpful if 1 rep users who have had their post flagged and removed as spam were automatically destroyed? There is an [old feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165311/186281) about that.

Comment: Also on the nuking accounts thing - most spammers we see use an account once and then abandon it. It's debatable whether leaving them there does any damage, really, since their profiles aren't linked from any posts (all nuked) and they're not going to use them again.

Comment: Other than that profile spamming is a thing, and awareness of existing spam helps get rid of dormant spam accounts.

Comment: @rene After... what appears to be a vigorous discourse on the tavern? Yer right. I'm not actually opposed to 5 flags, just certain aspects of decision making.  I've removed that bit

Comment: @JourneymanGeek fair enough, retracted

Comment: _"I'd prefer some more direct human input, personally."_ Users explicitly register a MetaSmoke account, explicitly setup autoflagging, which involves checking a checkbox with a big red warning that tells the user they're basically granting MS access to their account. Enabling autoflagging on one's account isn't a _"click-and forget"_ action. It takes conscious effort.

Comment: See example above. Not *that* conscious. They're explicitly saying "Flag for me, I trust the system will do the right thing" *Not* actually looking at the post and deciding, which is pretty much the definition of "direct human input".

Comment: So, you want to remove all of the automation from the flagging?

Comment: @Cerbrus what gave you that idea? JMG is simply suggesting that *some* of it remain non automatic.

Comment: @terdon: And that's exactly what's planned. There will always be direct input from _at least_ one user required to spam-nuke a post. That's why they don't want to set the autoflagging limit to 6.

Comment: @Cerbrus I know, and so does JMG. You seemed to think that this answer was suggesting we "remove all of the automation from the flagging" and it doesn't suggest anything of the sort. I was just replying to your comment there.

Comment: @terdon: I guess I misunderstood his last comment, then.

Comment: @Cerbrus I'd like the folks who are active on, and/or help run the sites decide what's an appropriate level of input, and I'm uncomfortable with the decision on spam primarily made automatically, with minimal input from folks on the site. I'm *not* comfortable with the  decision on how many flags are done being made for us. That's basically what the answer above says.

Comment: so TLDR: I'd like to keep auto-flags at the current level *unless* a site explicitly asks for more flagging. Opt *in* over opt *out*

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: How would you propose this opt-in would work on the (177) sites on this network? How would an site opt in?

Comment: Get a mod to request it - we're either elected by the community, or picked to represent them after all. Shouldn't be too hard for one to message or drop a charcoal admin an email.

Comment: The alternative is literally "We're doing this" and despite their good work, I don't think anyone really *should* be deciding on behalf of the network how things should work.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: How would you make ___all___ moderators aware this thing exists, and that it requires their input? What if the moderators on a specific website are divided? Also, please don't overlook the amount of input MetaSmoke has had from community managers and other moderators. I'm stating the obvious, but I'd like there to be no confusion: This ins't just some hacked-together tool that's gonna take over the network, skynet style. It's not "someone" deciding how things on the network work. It's a group of users, moderators and CMs streamlining spam deletion.

Comment: @Cerbrus the point is that this group of users isn't involved in all the sites. And they aren't SE employees, they're just a group of volunteers who've declared a war on spam (which they've been winning because, frankly, they're so good at it). This doesn't change the fact that they aren't members of the relevant communities so this proposal would give this group of "outsiders" a certain degree of "power" to decide how *this* community does things. That's what seems worrying. So giving the choice to the community instead of the group of outside users seems reasonable.

Comment: @terdon How would that be significantly different with the power outsiders get from the association bonus? A organization aside, outsiders (in the particular SE community sense) are already given plenty of power on a new site they look into, which seems to be by design

Comment: @Magisch the difference is that when you come in and create an account as an individual user, you then get involved in the community and become a part of it. If you just create an account, never visit the site, and only cast flags, you never have the chance to understand the local culture. And flagging culture does actually vary across the network.  Imagine a group of people who love cleaning. They offer to come into all public building and clean them. For free! Wouldn't it be reasonable to first ask the people working in those buildings though?

Comment: In your analogy, the people working (read: not living, not owning) those buildings would probably have no input as to who cleans and when. The building owners would probably, yeah. But I mean what I said seriously. Across the network, things like HNQ drive people from outside site communities to smaller sites - and they usually bring distinct effects like vote inflation and loads of off topic comments with them. In keeping with your idea here, do you think this is significantly different? Does the reason I come to the site (seeing spam vs seeing an outwardly interesting post) matter much?

Comment: In both cases I know almost nothing about the site beyond a tiny snippet out of the complete picture. And in both cases I'm not liable to read meta or get to know the culture.

Comment: You still actually read the posts you vote on in hnq. And if you were actually there I'd say you're not auto voting. So ... Very bad comparison @magisch.

Comment: @Magisch no, and the HNQs list is one of the most annoying features of SE for precisely that reason. If I could remove the sites I participate in from HNQ I would do so gladly. But that's besides the the point. What JMG is suggesting here is that whether or not outside help is wanted should be down to the communities to decide. Since this meta post is suggesting that this change can be switched off for sites that don't want it, it is presumably possible to do it on a site-by-site basis. If so, it could also be possible to have it off and only turn it on on a site-by-site basis.

Comment: @Magisch if my employees called me (I'm the owner) telling that the cleaning service, is stepping on their tows, removing stuff they should not and are not listing to them, I would probably change cleaning service. With this comment I only like to arise awareness how important it is to listen to all site specifici moderators (they represent that community), enforcing some overall "That's what this meta states" will only create troubles and probably for a spam post removed earlier it's not worth it.

Comment: ^^ This to me does not mean you can't raise 5 auto flags or even mod nuke it, but probably only that you need to do some site x site feature.

Comment: @Cerbrus that is quite literally a problem that something like this needs to solve. I keep hearing that "its too hard to get input from all 177 sites" - but we're stakeholders - we run the sites and create the content there. A successful project isn't just about statistics and shiny - its about people, and communication and certain aspects of it feel like [autofac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autofac) . "YOU HAVE SPAM! WE CLEAN SPAM! MORE CLEAN!" when we actually want folks keeping an eye out for spam the old fashioned way too.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: _"when we actually want folks keeping an eye out for spam the old fashioned way too."_ Again, that's why there's a limit on the automated flags. Spam posts still require user input to be deleted. Keep in mind that these auto-flags are only cast on content of which the system is (99.75%) _certain_ it's spam. That's why there are "spam weight" and reason count conditions  on these autoflags. I guess ___I___ just don't understand why one would not want _absolute spam_ to be deleted with as little users getting involved as possible. Imo, every user that sees spam is one too many.

Comment: Cause if smoke detector/charcoal goes down, those users would be our backup. There's certain situations where as a mod, I'd actually like to see spam flags so I know what's going on. I occasionally get slightly confused spam flags  under "other". Its harder for me to nuke accounts. And well, at some point spammers are going to evolve their tactics anyway, so I would rather a system that works well, and keeps people involved in the loop for "strange things" over just getting rid of all of it with minimal intervention cause "its more efficient.

Comment: There aren't logs of spam deletions available to mods?

Comment: not really? Certainly not obviously in the mod workflow. These days I just keep an eye on the Smoke Detector bot on tavern on the meta when I'm around to see what's going on.

Comment: That seems like a completely different shortcoming then ;-)
Also, I don't mean to be rude, but the second half of that comment is grossly underestimating the daily effort put into recognizing new types of spam, and registering keywords / methods to catch said spam.

Comment: Oh, I mean pretty massive evolution [profile spamming is kind of a thing now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303746/spam-profiles-are-getting-my-goat-could-we-have-better-tools-for-mods-to-deal-w) and there's pretty much nothing that can deal with it at the moment.

Answer (score 18):

I am grateful to the Charcoal and SmokeDetector developers and users for their substantial, commendable efforts to fight spam on Stack Exchange sites.

However, in relation to this specific proposal, I want to comment on a specific point, which is made twice by the OP:

> It will only take **1 or 2** manual flags from users to spam-nuke an autoflagged post, instead of the current 3. [...]
>
> There are currently 3 manual flags required in addition to the automatic flags to nuke a post; this increase proposal still retains **at least one** manual flag.

*(Emphasis mine.)*

A reduction to **two** manual flags would still permit human peer review, i.e. confirmation or disputation of a human's decision by another human. This seems to me to be the minimal essential safety check against humans going rogue. It is less safe than requiring three manual flags, but at least it does not forego peer review altogether; and of course it would cut the humans' workload by (about) a third. I would be supportive of this.

A reduction to **one** manual flag would eliminate this crucial safety check. I would not be supportive of this.

*Edit: I see that Monica Cellio has already made [essentially the same point](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/307597), and [so has](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/307589/) Mad Scientist.*

Comment: From one of the graphs above, [four flags isn't a significant difference from 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kph8d.png). We have systems in place that review everything reported retroactively. I plan to modify those to require at least two eyes on everything. I don't know of an instance where we've flagged a false positive and missed it - but you're welcome to review the data for yourself.

Comment: @Undo, *"[using] four [machine] flags [out of six] isn't a significant difference from [using three out of six]"*. That's considering only one metric: time to delete. But on the metric of human workload, the difference presumably would be, as I mentioned in my answer, much more significant: a reduction of (about) a third.

Comment: @Undo, *"I plan to modify those to require at least two eyes on everything.*" The implication that you would do this *in the future* seems to contradict the part of the OP's proposal that says "Multiple people review each post we catch, whether it's autoflagged or not", which suggests the system *already* is set up such that it will require human peer review even if the proposal is implemented. (As an aside: if the system does already require human peer review, then either the proposal makes no sense, or else it uses "nuke" in a *very* misleading way. "Nuke" indicates irrevocable deletion.)

Comment: Currently, you have to have at least three people look at everything before it's deleted. With 5 automatic flags, it would only be one person to nuke. I'm going to add another person to review after the nuke so we can't miss any false positives (which, historically, are 1 in thirty thousand) - essentially keeping at least two eyes watching for false positives.

Comment: @Undo, "Review after nuke" is self-contradictory, for the reason given in my previous comment, i.e. that in the context of computer systems, "[nuke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBAN)", like "[shred](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shred_(Unix))", means irrevocable deletion. Please can you write comprehensibly?

Comment: @sampablokuper - "nuke" in this case means deletion. What Undo means is looking at what happened *after the fact* - reviewing the situation in hindsight, after the post has been deleted.

Comment: Nuking a post *is* reversible by a ♦ moderator. It's something we don't want to happen; it's extremely unlikely to happen, but if it does, we can fix things together.

Comment: Glorfindel and Mithrandir, perhaps "nuking" means something different in Elrond, but if the OP wants their post to be understood by the average SO user, it would help a lot if the term could be used according to the common convention in computing contexts, i.e. to mean deleting irrevocably. If you & Undo & the OP are appealing to some kind of in-group anti-pattern redefinition of common terms, then that practice should be dropped before attempting to bring others into the discussion, or else entirely avoidable misunderstanding will occur, as has happened here :(

Comment: I agree with sampablokuper here, @Undo - it'd be kinda nice to nuke the "nuke" terminology, since it suggests something rather more... *final* than what is actually being discussed here. Trivia: I have a bookmarklet on my phone named "nukethis" that takes whatever post is on my screen, offensive-deletes it, and then destroys its author with a reason that ensures their IP can't post anything for the next little while. That's about as close as we can get to "nuke" here.

Comment: Thanks, Shog9 :) Incidentally, s/Elrond/Rivendell/ . Apparently, it's a long time since I read Tolkien...

Comment: @sampablokuper for better or for worse, "spam-nuke" is the most common (short) term I've seen for the 6-flag = auto-deletion mechanism. I think I've even seen some of SO's mods call it that :/

Comment: For clarification, when we ‘review’ a post we’re generally looking at a mirrored copy that we store in our web dashboard, that’s why we can still see it after it’s been ‘nuked’ (or deleted)

Comment: @mrbrig: that's for worse, surely.

Comment: @angussidney, thanks for the clarification. However (and this is not directed at you personally, just at the [groupthink](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Groupthink&oldid=828458914) that resulted in it happening): storing "a mirrored copy ... in our web dashboard" - i.e. migrating, archiving, or quarantining - is so far from what "nuke" conventionally means in computing that I can't even begin to express how mind-bogglingly misleading it is to use that word to describe it.

Answer (score 6):

Related to the issues of transparency, perhaps an automated comment under a post that's been autoflagged would be helpful in understanding and sighting Smoke Detector activity in situ so to speak, as opposed to needing to make a search of [Meta Smoke](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/) or a monthly report, as [suggested by Shog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/307613/310756).

Of course these tools could still be made available, but an auto comment sits with the post and is more easily accessible. It would also show any potential manual flaggers, that it's been auto-flagged. To assist user's not knowing about the project the auto comment could include a link to the [Charcoal wiki](https://charcoal-se.org/) or a canonical post on Meta, perhaps the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq), when/of Smokey is added to the  FAQ.

Comment: The spammers will figure out we have a more aggressive system for removing spam and will spam more aggressively.

Comment: which feeds the spam filters, which gets rid of them faster, Don't forget, smokey feeds spamram. I actually think *some* feedback - maybe via one of the flags being custom might be a nice touch over the current system

Comment: @Ano In the unlikely event that spammers review their own posts (they don't) it would not be unequivocally a bad thing for them to discover that we dislike them and are taking action. Sure, most are obviously unrepentant, and giving them *too much* details about our countermeasures would be stupid. But I don't think this is anywhere near crossing that line.

Comment: @Ano erm, keen spammers can already read all this? And will have access to everything the general community has.

Comment: @Ano if anything, it will make the spammers realize they better spend their time and resources on other sites, with less spam protection. :)

Comment: There are several good reasons NOT to have automated comments coming from Smoke Detector or its users. The primary reason is that SD users can't actually *do anything* to help someone whose post has been automatically deleted - that requires a moderator. "Hey, we deleted your post for [reasons] - if we got it wrong, please help us train our classifier!" isn't an awesome introduction to the site. Beyond that, we know from experience that telling spammers *exactly* what got their spam identified just results in a long, tedious process of banning every possible unicode representation of a phone #

Comment: But probably the best reason not to do comments is simply that they're *comments* - the expectation of most readers is that there's a human behind them who is going to be responsive to feedback. When that's not forthcoming, there's no telling what the reaction will be. I've had spammers do public record searches and threaten my family; you don't normally expect that from a spam *flag*, because it's completely anonymous. Expecting volunteers to stand by their mistakes is fine; expecting them to tolerate abuse isn't.

Comment: @Shog9 well I was thinking Smokey would make the auto comment - so  stalking smokey will be hard - but if you think it's going to make it easier for spammers - the thing is - they can click on the spam tag on any site and they will find all they need to know - maybe the comment will make it easier. Yep as for expecting a reply - the user could be directed to charcoal chat. Anyway- it's no big deal - it was an idea thrown into the ring for evaluation, and it sounds like it's not such a good idea. Sorry about your family being threatened - too many psychos out and about

Answer (score 6):

<sup>Note of warning I have not read all of the answers here. I'm sure what I wrote is duplicated somewhere.</sup>

I like smokey, it works amazingly well. Yes I would trust *it* to fully automatically delete spam.

I'm going to point out some "issues" and then speek to them (we are on meta after all).

There are two issues with moving from 3 flags to 5.

1. Do we really need the extra speed? On the site I moderate, we do not get that much spam. (Smokey has auto flagged 8 posts, total). With the user base, and the amount of questions we get per day we really don't need a machine gun on our spam. A friendly [bear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smokey_Bear) watching over the site seems sufficient for us.
2. Humans are far more likely to get something wrong then a machine. Yes smokey is correct somewhere around 99.7%, but what is the human error rate? (I've made mistakes, clicked the wrong button etc.) Now with only one human vote, you've removed the human self check. A human error could get by with just one person voting. I don't like that idea. (There are users on BSE I would not trust with that responsibility, and I know there are some on your sites too.) *We would essentially be giving whoever came across that auto flagged post moderator powers.*

I understand that smokey would be auto flagging only the most obvious spam posts. Posts that SE should be filtering out.

In that light I have no problem with smokey moving to 5 flags. I trust smokey, and if it is that good at finding the really bad spam I *think* there is no way of a user to mess up. Say we have a spam post, if the user thinks it is not spam (somehow) then the post waits in the queue for the next guy.

About the speed, It's spam. The quicker we get rid of it the better. We may not "need" the speed, but there is no harm in having spam disappear quicker.

Go for it.

#### Remember... Only YOU Can Prevent Spam Posts.

Comment: Please note that only posts that _could_ get 5 automated flags, are those of which the system is absolutely certain it's spam. Out of the nearly 30k spam posts in SD's history that meet the strict criteria to receive 5 auto-flags, there hasn't been a single false positive. Any post that doesn't meet those criteria won't get 5 auto-flags, which in turn means more users will need to get involved to get less spammy posts deleted. Basically, the system is conservative, by design.

Answer (score 2):

## Suggestion #1: site transparency

Provide a clear list of what was flagged and removed as spam (either as a separate review queue, or just a list). This way the site community will have an option to <strike>gamify getting another Gold badge for reviews</strike> review the spam removal history for accuracy.

## Suggestion #2: user transparency

Make it crystal clear to a user that their post was removed as spam, with an obvious link of how to dispute that (and a solid workflow procedure to dispute). This may not address 100% of false positives some of which may be from new/unregistered users; but it will at the very least hopefully reduce the amount of grief and upset from false positived users.

Comment: #2 is something that would need to be done SE-side. #1, however, we do have: https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/sites/dash (the Autoflagged tab)

Comment: I just posted something [similar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307585/a-machine-can-flag-spam-automatically-can-it-do-better/307613#307613), but disagree vehemently with #2 - this is essentially handing a roadmap to spammers / trolls. As with *any* mishandled post, a wronged user should flag for moderator attention and let them determine what action is needed - there shouldn't be two paths to redress for users based on who flagged them. What's missing right now is tooling that allows moderators quick access to Smoke Detector from such a post; fortunately, that's much easier to fix.

Comment: @Shog9 - I should have been more clear but #2 was proposing just that - a flag to moderators. I merely wanted to make it obvious and visible for benefit of some random newbie who never heard of moderator flag and won't know what the little "flag" link does; via a custom message we have on, say, duplicate VTC Qs

Comment: We do do a bit better now about showing the *reason* for deletion on posts, @DVK - but flag is all there is, for anyone. That and /contact. [This is what a spam-deleted post looks like to its author](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00QCw.png) - making that more explanatory is outside the scope of this discussion (incorrectly-deleted posts happen rarely, but happen without Smoke Detector's involvement more than with it). That said, don't hesitate to propose a more intuitive UI there if you have ideas.

Comment: @Shog9 - imho, merely adding something like "If you think this was marked as spam in error, click the 'flag' link to alert the moderators" seems more than sufficient.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not against this idea - but using actual user accounts to do botted automation is a dodgy hack that should be rectified before pushing this further in my opinion. Fair enough while it was an experiment - but now this is getting a little bit beyond the experiment phase.

How reasonable would it be to create a SmokeDetector user that has the privilege to cast multiple spam votes? I think if we got that happening we would fix the transparency issues highlighted in other answers.

Once this transparency is achieved, I would feel comfortable with the idea of bumping it up to 4 votes (ie, 2 manual votes still required). Once we trial that for a while, running the graphs again should give us insight as to how we should proceed.

Comment: Using bot accounts is a common suggestion. Creating one super account isn't likely to happen, because it requires SE dev time, which is in short supply. Using multiple bot accounts is a debate we're going to have, but not at the same time as this debate about 5 flags

Comment: I do not like the idea of using fake / separate accounts for this. Philosophically, that breaks tradition: it allows whatever user controls the account(s) extra privilege over other users. Practically-speaking, it removes the cost of getting it wrong: everyone signing up for this does so with the understanding that they're still responsible for their actions, even if they allow those actions to be dictated to some extent by SD; they have their accounts to lose if they take that responsibility lightly.

Comment: @Shog9 - That's actually a very convincing point of view... A good thing about a special user is that if it goes haywire there is only one user to ban (and presumably it would make it relatively easy to find all the damage it caused). I also imagined that such a user would have little other privileges (ie, it can't vote/answer/comment/etc) so it wouldn't be a useful account excepting for spam flagging. But the potential loss of accountability is a very good counterargument...

Comment: @Shadow If the thing goes haywire, we have other ways of dealing with that. It'll get shut down very quickly by whoever notices, and if necessary we can revoke the API access tokens we have.

Comment: In that case, the only 'pro' left that I can think of is the ability for a reviewer to know whether what is in front of them is there because of a bot or humans. To which I'd argue that robo-reviewers are probably unlikely to change their habits because they realise that they're having a final say. So I guess I concede. It still seems kinda hacky, but it's hacky for good reasons.

Comment: @Shog9 interesting perspective, although to me, a few SE condoned bot accounts seems a more legitimate direction for the project than a bunch of people essentially signing up for a sock-puppet bot (although I agree its doing fantastic work in this case). Would people feel the same if SOCVR signed up to a ML bot that auto-closed questions?

Comment: I think that depends a lot on how such a system was operated, @mbrig. It ain't like SD just started this yesterday; they were honing the accuracy of their detection for a *long* time prior to doing any assisted flagging, and have been extremely careful with that since. Even now, no one is suggesting that SD unilaterally spam-delete questions - the open discussion is primarily focused on how much of a *force multiplier* it is for human flaggers.

Comment: @Shog9 and Shadow, I continue to disagree; it would be cleaner with dedicated bots account, in the end the bot developers are always responsible (a random selection of 300 users is very hard to keep responsible), it's messy for moderators and it's gaming flags and badge (not that I care, but some do). Maybe yeah if instead the developers account were used but probably 1 bot account connected to a 1 single developers would be best, but I guess it is best we discuss this on another meta and concentrate on number on flags that SD should cast on this meta.

Comment: I'm *against* dedicated bot accounts, @Petter. If you disagree that it would be cleaner, then you're not disagreeing with me.

Comment: @Shog9 I feel you are wrong, knowing you are right, I just cant understand why, if I get some time I will put up another meta... and try with my English to hash out better my idea...

Comment: Ok, so you *do* want dedicated accounts, @Petter? I think that's something we'd have to be very, very careful with; the entire system is designed around individual responsibility, and a bot account separates that from any one individual. Try to focus on what problems such an arrangement would solve, and how we might reduce the risk of error or abuse.

Comment: @Shog9 Yes either developer accounts (like Andy, comment bot) or 1 single bot account connected to developer profile (like BR, natty), the developer can't flag when bot does, this makes it clear for moderator what is going on (they know why flagged), the flag goes either to developer (merit) or to bot account, but this rule is not directly related to SD more a general rule. This random picking a user from a +300 users base seems messy and without merit.

Comment: *To flag 5 times you just would need 5 developers (hence probably not a problem for SD), but yeah the users connected to bot account can't flag themself* If the bot does a messy you just follow the developer link in [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6817005/natty) and you will find out who is to blame and can fix stuff

Comment: Just for sake of argue, immagine you have 300 users and miss flag 300 times, that however would be only 1 miss flag per user (how would you blame that user?). This is not the case for SD but just trying to explain how the logic of responsibility fails, also since badges are a thing for some, what merit did these 300 users have?, how can a moderator easily identify that it was auto-flagged if they see random users (they can't even get experience on who is who)

Comment: I think you should write an answer, @Petter; there's a lot to unpack in those last two comments. While you're writing that, consider this: one bot would be insufficient. Quite possibly 5 bots would be insufficient. A user with 15 rep starts out with 10 flags and that doesn't increase significantly until there are hundreds of past helpful flags - so on a site with a spam problem you'd need a lot of bots. If you wanted to raise 5 flags/post on 40 posts a day, that'd be 200 bots *minimum*. Nevermind the crazy optics of even *creating* 200 network-wide sockpuppets.

Comment: @Shog9 5 * 40 / 10 is 20, not 200.

Comment: Naw, @FTP is right, I'm not thinking clearly here. 20 bots is still a problem, but less of one than 200.

Comment: Yeah you were counting votes rather than bots... but this deviates from my suggestion to some degree. I don't think having an army of bots is any cleaner than an army of users (although we still may gain the ability to easily tell if it was human intervention of a bot making the call)

Comment: @Shog9 I will reflect some and if I write down something it will be a new meta post; a question, both since I'm heavily involved in bots myself (I prefer to not provide the answer) and this discussion is not directly related to SD, even if I already suggested this on my already existing answer on this post. Related to number of flags needed there is some discussion in comments under my answer. 5-6 dev accounts would probably be enough for the current auto-flagging

Comment: @Shog9 Just as a point of information: starting from 10 flags and assuming that your flags are immediately marked helpful (as is the case for spam), you'll have 100 flags by the end of the 23rd day (assuming you cast your max # of flags on each site, every day (unrealistic)).

Comment: There's nothing which says a change-over to using bots needs to be a cut-over. It could easily be made such that the bots are given priority to flag and the currently signed up user accounts are used once the bots can no longer flag on a site. Within a minimum of 15 days, 5 bots total would be flagging all 40 hypothetical posts. Obviously, it would end up taking more time, but there's no reason that we must create a large number of bots, if we're willing to take a bit of time.

Comment: That works on stack overflow, @makyen. The site that gets 3 spam posts a week until it gets 20 a day for one day is more troublesome. Eventually, it works. But how long it takes varies.

Comment: @Shog9 True. The reality is that any amount of available flags could be exceeded, should spammers decide that they want to concentrate on a site, or the network as a whole. Thus, keeping the supply of user accounts which are currently auth'd, as a backup supply of available flags, would be a reasonable course of action, unless moving to some situation where special account(s) are allocated with unlimited flags.

Comment: The fact that "any amount of available flags could be exceeded" is one of the major things that keeps pushing us towards using real user accounts. At a vaguely-educated guess, we have about 250 users now signed up for autoflagging, probably with around _ten thousand_ flags between them, on a single site. That's really quite hard to exhaust.

Comment: @Art how many people do you have that are dev/bot admin? Hence have power to shut down and are active in charcoal?

Comment: *I'm not pushing for some immediate change just trying to understand if using their account (similar as Andy did)  it would be enough for auto-flagging*

Comment: @Petter Everyone with privileges, including mods, has the power to shut autoflagging down. There are 5 admins (2 of whom have additional developer privileges), who have the power to re-enable it.

Comment: @ArtOfCode: To clarify: "Everyone with privileges" includes _everyone_ that has autoflagging set up, right?

Comment: @Shog9 Fundamentally, allowing a bot to act on my behalf separates responsibility (mine) from control (bot's). If its actions cause me to be banned, I have no recourse, except to deactivate it, and apologize. I can't see how this is better than having dedicated accounts, where responsibility is placed directly on the developer, rather than implicitly so.

Comment: That *is* recourse, @jpaugh. You're using a tool - that doesn't absolve you of responsibility. In practice, if something went horribly wrong we'd probably disable both the tool *and* the folks using it until the problem could be sorted out. But as with Petter's concerns, this probably should be a separate discussion if we're discussing hypothetical situations.

Comment: @Cerbrus Negative. Everyone who has SmokeDetector privileges. That's the list hardcoded into Smokey's config, available [here on GH](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/SmokeDetector/blob/master/rooms.yml#L10) (plus all mods).

Comment: @Shog9 Yes, that is status quo; which is why I won't enable smoke detector, no matter how accurate it is.

Comment: @jpaugh the current system is there because it's both convenient and gives folks a way to participate if they want to. Nobody is trying to force you to do that and not signing up is absolutely your prerogative. Other people might trust charcoal enough to sign up, knowing full well that their accounts are on the line if there's a mess up. FWIW, most of the charcoal members are also signed up, so our accounts are _also_ on the line if something goes wrong.

Comment: I'm with @jpaugh on this. And if the SE interface asserts that user X has taken an action, other users should be able to trust this assertion. Currently, they can't. Something like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Bot_policy would be *far* more transparent & accountable. 3rd-party bots shouldn't masquerade as human users for the sake of any [CRUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRUD) operation except maybe retrieval. I'm disappointed SE considers it acceptable, let alone on this scale. Spam-fighting is important, but hardly justifies such a serious abuse of accountability as this.

Comment: @sampablokuper Where do you get that lack of accountability from? Every spam flag cast by our project is public record.

Comment: @Magisch, from the discussion above. If you think the approach taken by SE and SD is more accountable/transparent that this discussion suggests, then please link to evidence for that. I am open to being corrected if I was mistaken. Thanks :)

Comment: @sampablokuper For one, you can view every single automatic flag. It shows who flagged, too. It also shows who fed back and why the post was flagged. Here: https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/flagging/logs

Comment: Essentially you can see everything about us - it's all public record. In fact, you could go right now and look at every single feedback I've ever given, if you wanted. You could also look at every single autoflag that was ever cast in my name.

Comment: @Magisch, thanks. The problem still stands: by simply looking at StackExchange websites, it is impossible to distinguish for sure between the actions a bot has taken in your name, and actions that you yourself took. (Also, I am a Stack Exchange user, not an Erway Software user, and have no particular reason to trust anything stated within the erwaysoftware.com domain.)

Answer (score -1):

My concern is alerting users in general to this.  Perhaps there is **advice** to avoid getting one's question/post inadvertently marked as spam.  This may be especially important to any links posted ... Such as 'do' this or 'don't do' that, etc....

Comment: While a general user's "borderline-spammy" question might be detected by SmokeDetector, it absolutely won't reach the threshold to be automatically flagged.

Comment: @Cerbrus good to know

Answer (score -4):

I also oppose having it down to only one human.  Keep it two or more.

Do spam-flags put the post/answer on a review queue?  That would (I think) get those last two votes in more quickly, if they are needed.

Comment: There's no review queue built into Stack Exchange for spam, no. The only review queue that spam realistically gets put into is the one that we operate on metasmoke, Charcoal's web dashboard.

Comment: Perhaps that's worth a change.  One spam flag, auto or manual, and reviewers are alerted.  Spam is bad, but not bad enough to risk losing good posts due to four erroneous auto-flags and one mistake or accident by a human.

Comment: That'd be worth a feature-request here on MSE. It's not something Charcoal can implement since we're not on the SE team, but I'd be happy to see it.

Answer (score -9):

On the single piece of "autoflag transparency", a thought, or several

Rather than needing accounts with special privileges such as "multiple flags per post" make, and register system-wide, 5 accounts. CharcoalAutoflag1 through 5, say, or come up with something better. They would perhaps need extra flagging volume, but nothing special flag-per-post. They simply pile on in the same way that real people do. Indeed, if they are accurate, they could even get their extra flagging volume the same way real users do, by having their flags classified as helpful.

If it's:

99% spam, CharcoalAutoflag1 flags it.

99.5 CharcoalAutoflag2 also flags it

99.75 CharcoalAutoflag3 also flags it

99.95 CharcoalAutoflag4 also flags it

99.99 CharcoalAutoflag5 also flags it (or 99.999 or however many decimal places you want to put there.)

I agree with the general idea that the automated flagging seems good from a spam-removal view, but if it's pretending to be real users doing the flagging, it's not at all apparent if a post is being flagged by people or bots. Having whichever account correlates to the highest level of certainty post a comment to the effect that "Charcoal's automated spam detection evaluates this post as 99.5% likely to be spam" or similar message would also be helpful (perhaps you are doing this, I've hardly spent the evening combing though the whole backstory to formulate the commentary on a small part of the process I had not known about until today.)

Comment: If you edit spam out of a spam post, it is _much less likely_ to get flagged as spam. Editing spam out is counter-productive in getting the spammer banned.

Comment: SmodeDetector isn't leaving any automated comments. Making these automated flags recognizable as such is indeed an concern, but I'm not sure comments are the solution.

Comment: @Catija I have edited to remove the incidental comment portion that has you all ignoring the content related to the question. You may delete the 3 now-irrelevant comments and get back to the actual question.

Comment: You can feel free to blame that part of your post for the downvotes but you're not the first person here suggesting using special accounts, so you might actually read the other answers before picking on that as an explanation. As an example, see the comments on [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/307614/284336). Your answer may be more detailed, but it still suggests something that's unlikely to be a good choice.

Comment: You've missed the reason why multiple accounts are required - each account has limited flags. Although your idea makes sense up until that point, the "99%" would need to be distributed between each bot otherwise the 1st bot will run out of flags way before the 5th one.

Comment: One of the reasons why this doesn't work is that spam happens in waves. We would need a whole bunch of accounts with the assoc bonus, because a small site like say graphic design could get almost nothing for a year and suddenly 20 posts a day out of left field.