# Most of the spam I receive is on webapps.SE

Tags: discussion, spam, specific-site

I don't have statistics to backup my claims, but I hope you do.

I just flagged an answer as spam on webapps.SE. Most of the spam I reported are:

1. Posted as answers
2. On https://webapps.stackexchange.com
3. The moderators are relatively slow to remove it (understandably, it's okay)

I get a spam answer on every question more or less, and that's an insane number. On other websites I very rarely, if ever get spammed.

I try to avoid asking questions on that site because of spam. The other day, someone posted please help me please, with a photo of a trapped women, and it really bothered me. That was the first time I saw a spammer uploading an image; usually they just write text.

Is spam is higher on that site than average or is it my bad luck? If it's higher then why?

BTW, I'm a member on smaller sites than webapps.se, and I don't get spammed. Something is weird there.

Comment: There's a coordinated effort to remove spam around the SE network (see [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307585/a-machine-can-flag-spam-automatically-can-it-do-better?rq=1) for example) and thanks to them most spam around the network is gone within seconds. I don't know if webapps is being hit by a particularly strong spam wave, but I would have brought this up with Charcoal.

Comment: @M.A.R.ಠ_ಠ Who's Charcoal?

Comment: WebApps is 16th in the network for volume of spam

Comment: @Lynob see [our website](https://charcoal-se.org/); basically, we detect & delete spam across the Stack Exchange network. If we miss a spam wave, we'd very much like to know about it :)

Comment: @CalvT does this stat holds true even for the last 3 months or so? That's when i noticed the increase in spam

Comment: @Lynob that's the last 30 days I believe. It's from the graph page of the website Glorfindel mentioned.