# Keyword-based spam detection to keep spam questions out of the network

Tags: discussion, questions, spam-detection

Over the course of the Winter Bash, I have encountered a lot of spam questions here on MSE, the common pattern among them being the keyword "keto diet" or simply "keto".

No doubt they are deleted as soon as they are posted (thanks to the active community), but isn't there a method already in place which helps prevent such cases? If not, is there a plan to introduce/try one?

To begin with, one can check the user's history of questions to see if they have been asking questions with similar keywords earlier, and whether those questions were closed/deleted. This can then be expanded to consider posts made by that user across the SE network to prevent spam.

Thoughts?

Comment: This literally is what smoke detector is. While I'd love to get the reputation - I think I ought to leave it to someone more closely linked with the project to answer

Comment: @JourneymanGeek is that a tool? Can you share the link?

Comment: There was also the click2fitness several times a day. All of this spamming has really irritated me. I have been amazed at how fast it disappears, though. In just about all instances the flag dialog took too long to load for me to flag.

Comment: @CinCout https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/120914/smokedetector

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307585/a-machine-can-flag-spam-automatically-can-it-do-better/ is worth a read. I've dropped a link to this question where folks can find it

Comment: Regarding part of the question: "user's history of questions" is usually not relevant, most spammers spam once and are gone forever. More accurate, spammers create new account for each spam post they make.