# What happened to the option to close a question as spam?

Tags: bug, vote-to-close

I am trying to close spam, looking for the other section. It isn't there. What happened?

[image: "Why should this question be closed?" menu]

Comment: Are you by any chance looking at [an extremely old screenshot of the vote to close dialog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2008/12/31/i-move-to-close-this-question/)?

Comment: Nope, just took this today @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog

Comment: No, I mean did you look at that old screenshot first showing a "spam" option in the list of close reasons, and assume that option is somehow gone in today's version?

Comment: No. Wasn't looking for a spam close option, looking for other @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog

Comment: You can flag as spam, not close as spam. It makes no sense to close spam, and it's really trivial.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's under community specific reasons - right at the bottom. You need to go deeper. But yeah you should flag not close spam

[image]

Comment: Okay. Thank you. Just trying to get it off as soon as it can as it unanimously bad but it will take longer than 5 views for a mod to see it.

Comment: Just for kicks' sake, it [was at one point possible to vote to close questions as spam](https://stackoverflow.blog/2008/12/31/i-move-to-close-this-question/).

Comment: Sorry but the answer is wrong, or misleading at best. We can't vote to close questions as spam. There is **no such close reason**.

Answer (score 22):

"Spam" is not and has never been a *close* reason. It's a *flag* reason.

Click on the `Flag` button instead of the `Close` button:
[image]

Comment: I know but also trying to close it as well. Where is the other section? My question is not about spam itself, just a bit of background on why i was trying to close

Comment: @Starshipisgoforlaunch Voting to close spam isn't necessary. In fact, voting to close spam with a custom reason can [arguably be harmful](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417870/11082165). Just flag it

Comment: I know, just want the spam of as soon as we can and 5 views will be sooner than a mod so i think its better for uncontroversial stuff @Brian61354270

Comment: Spam flags don't need a mod, just *enough* flags. - Brian's right here about the 'right' action to take. Its the answer you probably need, even if its not precisely the answer you want.

Comment: Okay very well @JourneymanGeek

Comment: @Starshipisgoforlaunch You shouldn't vote to close spam. It doesn't bring the question any closer to being deleted in the appropriate way (which requires 6 spam or rude flags, or a single one from a mod), and it confuses other people into thinking that closing is the right action. You can report the post in the Charcoal room for help in flagging. See [How can I get spam deleted faster?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/324617/323179)

Answer (score 5):

We don't close them as spam. Closing it just means you can't answer it. Spam needs more than that. It needs deletion. As such, we flag as spam, in which case the post will be deleted and locked after 6 flags.

Comment: It also needs the spammer user profile to be blocked. Yes, closing a question is for questions that are off-topic for a site, which eventually can be re-open if they are edited and made on-topic. We do not expect spam to become on-topic.