# Remove "All" tab from user profile's "Newest posts" widget

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

In each user profile page, there is a "Newest posts" section with grey/green rectangles marking each post as a Q(uestion) or A(nswer):

> [image: Newest posts with Q and A markers]

I think this looks awkward, particularly when you consider the space wasted when a user moves to the Answers tab from the All tab (the little mark saying that the listed posts are answered remains there, while serving no apparent purpose). It made me question the purpose of having an All tab in the first place. Questions and answers are on completely different levels, which is why we had these markers added in the first place. When would you want to see a combined list of a user's top-scoring questions and answers? I believe nobody would miss that tab if it were removed.

Answer (score 7):

> When would you want to see a combined list of a user's top-scoring questions and answers? I believe nobody would miss that tab if it were removed.

I'm using that tab quite often. I volunteer at the [Charcoal project](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291301/can-a-machine-be-taught-to-flag-spam-automatically), which aims to keep spam in check across the network. If a certain type of spam post (i.e. not the pharmacy ones) gets reported in the [Charcoal HQ chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq), I tend to visit the user's profile as well, to see if they have posted other inappropriate posts before which we might have missed. The easiest way to see them is an 'All' tab, because said posts can be both questions and answers. There are other ways (e.g. [searching for `user:726913`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A726913)) but none as convenient as this feature.

Answer (score 4):

If I’m understanding correctly, you’re talking about these, right?

[image: Icons]

These icons aren’t new, but the original icons were replaced with a new asset from [Stacks](https://stackoverflow.design/product/resources/icons/), our design system.

Comment: No, the question is not about the design change. It's about the "All" tab for Newest posts section, I edited the question to make it more clear.